# Arredondar números em C# sendo a casa decimal 0 ou 5

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo, arredondamento

Eu preciso arrendondar números de tal forma que tenham somente uma casa decimal valendo 0 ou 5.

Por exemplo

```
1 -> 1
1.1 -> 1.5
1.4 -> 1.5
1.5 -> 1.5
1.6 -> 2
2 -> 2
```

Alguém sabe de um jeito simples de fazer isso?

Comment: Como exatamente é essa regra? Acima de um inteiro `X`, arredonda pra `X.5`, e acima de `X.5` arredonda pra `X+1`? Em que contexto isso é usado?

Comment: Exatamente isso. Estou utilizando em um sistema de cauculos.

Comment: A solução do @mgibsonbr ficou melhor do que a minha para casos gerais. (Eu apenas armazenaria o resultado de `x - y` em uma variável temporária, para evitar repetir o cálculo 3 vezes)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn Bem observado! Na prática, *acho* que o compilador faria isso por si só, mas não custa deixar explícito...

Comment: @mgibsonbr pois é, também acho que sim, se ambas variáveis forem locais. Se pelo menos uma das duas não for local, *acho* que ele vai fazer 3 vezes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dada a especificidade da regra, sugiro separar a perte inteira da parte fracionária e - conforme desejado - acrescentar `0.5`, `1` ou nada:

```
int y = (int)x; // Descarta a parte decimal, arredondando pra baixo
if ( 0 < x - y && x - y <= 0.5 ) // Se a parte decimal for não-nula e menor ou igual a 0.5
    x = y + 0.5;                 // acrescenta 0.5 à parte inteira
else if ( 0.5 < x - y ) // Se a parte decimal for não-nula e maior a 0.5
    x = y + 1;          // arredonda pro próximo inteiro
```

Comment: Realmente, para um caso geral, essa solução é mais segura :)

Comment: Obrigado @mgibsonbr, pela preocupação!

Answer (score 7):

Para fazer esse tipo de arredondamento, supondo que seu valor esteja em uma variável `float` chamada `x`, pode-se fazer o seguinte:

```
x = (float)((int)((x + 0.4f) * 2.0f)) * 0.5f;
```

Se for `double`:

```
x = (double)((int)((x + 0.4) * 2.0)) * 0.5;
```

Para arredondar mais casas, como 1.51 para 2, pode utilizar `0.49f` (ou `0.49`) em vez de `0.4f`.

Quanto mais casas fossem necessárias, mais 9's seriam necessários depois do `0.4`.

Comment: Muito obrigado!! sou iniciante no C# não sabia desta solução.

Comment: @LucasAnjos Se `x = 1.51` o resultado será `1.5`. É isso mesmo que você quer?

Comment: @mgibsonbr bem notado! Vou editar, para contemplar casos com mais casas decimais.

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn Realmente, obrigado a dele se adapta melhor a meu caso.

Answer (score 4):

Resolvi responder porque há problemas nas outras respostas. Elas não estão erradas, existe solução melhor. Elas não contemplam negativos e há problemas de performance, embora isso não seja muito relevante. Uma delas acho uma solução feia e a outra desnecessariamente complicada. Espero não ter criado outros problemas na minha.

Eu começaria fazendo algo simples e elegante:

```
Ceiling(value * 2) / 2
```

Esta solução não resolve o problema dos números negativos, apenas mostra como pode ser simplificado. A solução dos negativos não torna muito mais complicado.

## Solução completa

Para os tipos `Decimal` e `double`. Se precisar, é muito fácil criar para `float`. Note que estou usando o compilador Roslyn (C# 6, veja mais informações em [Qual é o jeito correto de chamar as versões do C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101)). Se for necessário usar um compilador mais antigo é só eliminar os dois últimos `using` e chamar os métodos estáticos com o nome da classe. Se preferir usar sem *extension method* para não poluir o `namespace`, basta tirar o `this` no primeiro parâmetro.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("Decimal");
        for (var valor = -1M; valor <= 1M; valor += 0.05M) WriteLine("{0:N1} => {1:N1}", valor, valor.RoundMidPoint());
        WriteLine("Double");
        for (var valor = -1.0; valor <= 1.0; valor += 0.05) WriteLine("{0:N1} => {1:N1}", valor, valor.RoundMidPoint());
    }
}

public static class RoundUtil {
    public static Decimal RoundMidPoint(this Decimal value) => Sign(value) * Ceiling(Abs(value) * 2) / 2;

    public static double RoundMidPoint(this double value) => Sign(value) * Ceiling(Abs(value) * 2) / 2;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KhbeFW). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/epLzMo). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/RoundNumber.cs).

## Performance

Fiz outro teste para avaliar a performance dos algoritmos. Nele podemos notar que a minha solução é bem mais rápida. Ainda fiz um teste, não postado, sem resolver o problema dos negativos, que seria mais justo, e a diferença é maior, chega ser mais que o dobro do tempo. Fiz várias combinações e deixei só os mais relevantes. Espero não ter cometido injustiças. Na minha máquina os resultados foram consistentemente:

- Decimal Arredondando: 131 ms
- Double Arredondando: 138 ms
- Decimal mgibsonbr Arredondando: 240 ms
- Double carlosrafaelgn Arredondando: 247 ms

Código:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;
using System.Diagnostics;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var tempo = new Stopwatch();
        WriteLine("Decimal");
        tempo.Start();
        for (var valor = -10000M; valor <= 10000M; valor += 0.05M) valor.RoundMidPoint();
        tempo.Stop();
        WriteLine("Arredondando em ms: {0}", tempo.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        WriteLine("Double");
        tempo.Start();
        for (var valor = -10000.0; valor <= 10000.0; valor += 0.05) valor.RoundMidPoint();
        tempo.Stop();
        WriteLine("Arredondando em ms: {0}", tempo.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        WriteLine("Decimal Alternativo");
        tempo.Start();
        for (var valor = -10000M; valor <= 10000M; valor += 0.05M) valor.RoundMidPointAlt();
        tempo.Stop();
        WriteLine("Arredondando em ms: {0}", tempo.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        WriteLine("Double Alternativo");
        tempo.Start();
        for (var valor = -10000.0; valor <= 10000.0; valor += 0.05) valor.RoundMidPointAlt();
        tempo.Stop();
        WriteLine("Arredondando em ms: {0}", tempo.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

public static class RoundUtil {
    public static Decimal RoundMidPoint(this Decimal value) => Sign(value) * Ceiling(Abs(value) * 2) / 2;
    
    public static double RoundMidPoint(this double value) => Sign(value) * Ceiling(Abs(value) * 2) / 2;
    
    public static Decimal RoundMidPointAlt(this Decimal value) {
        int intPart = (int)value;
        decimal decimalPart = value - intPart;
        if (0 < decimalPart && decimalPart <= 0.5M) return intPart + 0.5M;
        else if (0.5M < decimalPart) return intPart + 1;
        else return intPart;
    }

    public static double RoundMidPointAlt(this double value) {
        int intPart = (int)value;
        double decimalPart = value - intPart;
        if (0 < decimalPart && decimalPart <= 0.5) return intPart + 0.5;
        else if (0.5 < decimalPart) return intPart + 1;
        else return intPart;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/exn6PR). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/txLqf0). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/RoundNumberPerformance.cs).

**Um *cast* não é uma operação mágica**, uma conversão é necessária e algo mais complexo que um `Ceiling` é realizado nele.

A performance pode não ser tão importante, mas não vejo motivo, neste caso, para evitar algo mais rápido. Além de tudo é mais simples.

Outra observação interessante é que o `Decimal` executa ligeiramente mais rápido que o `double` em todas as situações. Tem programador que acha que `double` é solução para problemas de performance para cálculos numéricos. Não em qualquer situação.

## Sugestões para futuras melhorias

Se for necessário dá para permitir a configuração do *midpoint* e arredondar para 0,4 ou 0,7 ao invés de 0,5, por exemplo. Não vou entrar em detalhes porque algumas definições precisas são necessárias para tratá-lo adequadamente.

Também é possível deixar configurar quantas casas decimais se deseja arredondar. Não fiz um teste mas a grosso modo isto seria muito fácil:

```
public static Decimal RoundMidPoint(this Decimal value, int decimais) => Sign(value) * Ceiling(Abs(value) * (2 * Pow(10, decimais - 1)) / (2 * Pow(10, decimais - 1);
```

Dá para pensar nisto de outras formas, não pensei muito a respeito. Pode ser melhor colocar *steps* e não a quantidade de decimais que deve arredondar. Enfim, é só uma ideia inicial para desenvolver. Provavelmente tem algo errado mas vai em exemplo inicial:

```
public static Decimal RoundStep(this Decimal value, Decimal step) => Sign(value) * Ceiling(Abs(value) / step) * step;
```

Certamente dá para achar um nome melhor para o método [`RoundMidPoint`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), aceito sugestões.