# Qual é o jeito correto de chamar as versões do C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clr

Parece haver alguma confusão com a nomenclatura das versões do C# e das tecnologias que estão relacionadas a ela.

Existe um C# 2005? Ou um C# 3.5? Qual a relação das versões do C# com o .NET, o Visual Studio, etc.?

Existem [livros que usam nomenclaturas como C# 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470191376) ([outro exemplo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599551)). Isto está correto?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

| C# | CLR | .NET Framework | .NET Core | Visual Studio | Lançamento |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | - | .NET (7.0) | Janeiro 2002 |
| 1.2 | 1.1 | 1.1 | - | .NET 2003 (7.1) | Abril 2003 |
| 2.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | - | 2005 (8.0) | Novembro 2005 |
|  |  | 3.0 | - |  | Novembro 2006 |
| 3.0 |  | 3.5 | - | 2008 (9.0) | Novembro 2007 |
| 4.0 | 4 | 4.0 | - | 2010 (10.0) | Abril 2010 |
| 5.0 |  | 4.5 | - | 2012 (11.00) | Agosto 2012 |
|  |  | 4.5.1 | - | 2013 (12.0) | Outubro 2013 |
|  |  | 4.5.2 | - |  | Maio 2014 |
| 6.0 |  | 4.6 | - | 2015 (14.0) | Julho 2015 |
|  |  | 4.6.1 | - | 2015 Update 1 | Novembro 2015 |
|  |  | 4.6.2 | 1.0 | 2015 Update 3 | Julho 2016 |
|  |  |  |  |  | Agosto 2016 |
| 7.0 |  |  | 1.1.1 | 2017 (15.0) | Março 2017 |
| 7.1 |  | 4.7 | 2.0 | 2017 (15.3) | Agosto 2017 |
| 7.2 |  | 4.7.1 |  | 2015 (15.5) | Novembro 2017 |
| 7.3 |  | 4.7.2 | 2.1 | 2017 (15.7) | Maio 2018 |
|  |  |  | 2.2 | 2017 (15.9) | Dezembro 2018 |
| 8.0 |  | 4.8 | 3.0 | 2019 (16.2) | Setembro 2019 |
|  | - | - | 3.1 | 2019 (16.3) | Novembro 2019 |
| 9.0 | - | - | 5 | 2020 (16.8) | Novembro 2020 |
| 10.0 | - | - | 6 | 2021 (17.0) | Novembro 2021 |
| 11.0 | - | - | 7 | 2022 (17.3) | Novembro 2022 |
| 12.0 | - | - | 8 | 2023 (17.8) | Novembro 2023 |
| 13.0 | - | - | 9 | 2024 (17.?) | Novembro 2024 |
| 14.0 | - | - | 10 | 2025 (18.?) | Novembro 2025 |
| 15.0 | - | - | 11 | 2026 (18.?) | Novembro 2026 |
| 16.0 | - | - | 12 | 2027 (18.?) | Novembro 2027 |

Há algumas curiosidades nesta listagem.

- Existe uma versão do C# chamada 1.2 mas ela é praticamente desconhecida. Além de pequenas mudanças foi criada a interface `IDisposable` e tudo o que é necessário para seu funcionamento. Alguns recursos, como o `IEnumerator`, passaram a usá-la.
- A versão do .NET Framework não é sincronizada com a versão da linguagem, afinal o .NET não é exclusivo do C#. Então alguém pode achar que porque existe um .NET 3.5 deve existir um C# 3.5. Não é o caso.
- A versão 3.0 do .NET no fundo é o .NET 2.0 com bibliotecas extras (WPF, WCF, WF, etc.).
- O Visual Studio inicialmente foi chamado de .NET porque todos os produtos da Microsoft seriam chamados assim, mas depois isto foi abandonado. Há uma marca comercial que segue os anos aproximados do seu lançamento e uma versão técnica. Versões anteriores ao 7.0 existiam mas não contemplavam o .NET.
- O .NET Framework 4.8 é o único que, em algum momento, será suportado por tempo indefinido e [não sofrerá evolução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).
- A versão seguinte do [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) 3.1 é o [.NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/), sem o termo Core no nome.

## Evolução do C#

- **C# 2.0** introduziu *generics*, *partial types*, *anonymous methods*, *nullable types*, acessibilidade separada para *getter/setter*, *method group conversions* (*delegates*), Covariância/Contra-variancia e `static class`es.
- **C# 3.0** introduziu variáveis locais implicitamente tipadas, inicializadores para objetos e coleções, propriedades auto-implementadas, *anonymous types*, *extension methods*, *query expressions*, *lambda expressions*, *expression trees* e *partial methods*.
- **C# 4.0** introduziu *dynamic binding*, *named* e *optional arguments*, *generic* co- e contravariance e *embedded interop types* ("NoPIA").
- **C# 5.0** passou ter *asynchronous methods* e *caller info attributes*.
- **C# 6.0** lançou o .NET Compiler Platform (Roslyn), inicializadores para *auto-properties*, *using* importando membros estáticos, *exception filters*, inicializadores de eventos, `await` dentro de `catch` e `finally`, *extension add methods*, inicializadores de coleções, propagação de `null`, *expression-bodied members*, operador `nameof`, interpolação de *strings*.
- **C# 7.0** apresentou tuplas, `out var`, literais binários e separadores, funções locais, `ref return`s, *expression-bodied* em todo lugar, *type switch* e `async` arbitrário.
- **C# 7.1** introduziu `async Main()`, `default` *literal expressions*, inferência em nomes de tuplas.
- **C# 7.2** introduziu semântica de referência para tipos por valor ( `ref`), `private proteced`, argumentos nomeados fora do final, literal numérico com underscore no final.
- **C# 7.3** passou ter campos fixos sem *pinagem* e uso em outros tipos que não eram possíveis, inicializadores em `stackalloc`, novas possibilidades de restrição genérica como `enum` e `delegate`, reatribuição de variáveis locais com `ref`.
- **C# 8.0** introduziu *default implementation* na interface, tipos por referência anuláveis, *patterns* recursivos, *async streams*, `using` por escopo, *ranges* e *indexes*, `??=`, sintaxe alternativa para *strings* interpoladas, `stackalooc` em contexto aninhado, `unmanaged` genérica em `struct`, `static` local function, membros `readonly`.
- **C# 9.0** introduziu *statements* soltos, *records*, `return` covariante, target-typed `new`, relaxamento na ordem de `ref` e `partial`, melhorias no *pattern matching*, skip locals init, *lambda discard parameters*, `int` nativos, atributo em função local, ponteiros para função, *lambdas* estáticas, melhoria no operador condicional, extensão de `GetEnumerator()`, inicializadores de módulo.
- **C# 10.0** tem `record struct`s, `global using`, *namespace por escopo em vez de bloco, mais *property pattern*, *record* pode selar `ToString()`, melhorias nos geradores de código e ferramentas para eles e para *debugger*, melhorias de sintaxe em alguns pontos e sobre *async*, inferência em *lambda*, construtor padrão sem parâmetros em `struct`, caller expression attribute, *strings* interpoladas constantes e melhorias nas outras.
- **C# 11.0** vem com `nameof(parameter)`, generic attributes, padrões de lista em *matching*, e eles agora funcionam com `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, literais de *string* UTF8 e bruta, propriedades podem ser `required`, campos por referência, interpolação permite quebra de linha, parâmetros de tipos com `Span` ou `stackalloc`, objetos `scoped`, tipos locais em um arquivo, operador de *shift* mais flexível e agora não sinalizado, `checked` agora pode ser personalizado, `IntPtr` pode ser um tipo numérico normal, cache de *delegates* estáticos.
- **C# 12.0** vem com parâmetros `ref readonly`, expressões de coleções e *spread*, aliases para qualquer tipo, verificação automático de `null` em parâmetro, construtores primários, parâmetros *default* em *lambda*, *arrays inline*, `nameof` para membros, atributo `Experimental` que começa com interceptadores (ainda não há garantias se como continuará na linguagem).
- **C# 13** - Campos automáticos em propriedades, `params Span<T>` e `stackalloc` para qualquer tipo *array*, *default in deconstruction*, `\e` em *strung*, melhorias no grupo de métodos, e *roles/extensions*.

Algumas restrições no uso das tecnologias combinadas existem:

- Não é possível usar C# 2 (é comum omitirmos o *release* na versão da linguagem) sem o .NET 2.0. Na verdade isto ocorre com várias versões pelo menos parcialmente
- O .NET 3.5 é necessário para usar o C# 3. No entanto a maioria das *features* do C# 3 podem ser usadas mesmo com .NET 2.0 ou 3.0.
- É possível selecionar a versão do .NET que sua aplicação deverá rodar. O VS 2005 em diante, em condições normais, não pode usar o .NET 1.0 e 1.1 como *target* da aplicação.
- Não é possível solicitar a uma versão do VS que ele se restrinja as *features* do C# de versões inferiores a instalada nele.
- Cada versão do VS tem um formato diferente do arquivo de projetos e uma conversão da antiga será feita automaticamente.

Não confundir .NET Framework com [.NET como plataforma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184716/101) como um todo que obviamente não tem versão. Ou com o .NET Core que é outro produto. O .NET 5 sim passa ser um nome oficial para o que antes era chamado de .NET Core.

O .NET possui algumas divisões como o FCL (Framework Class Library) que é um *superset* da BCL (Base Class Library). A BCL é necessária em qualquer implementação que desejam compatibilidade com o .NET (Mono por exemplo implementa toda a BCL e partes da FCL). Na FCL está incluso o Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc. A FCL faz menos sentido no .NET Core, o modelo mudou e os componentes são mais isolados.

O [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) (Common Language Runtime) é a máquina virtual que controla as aplicações escritas para o .NET. Note que ela é bem mais estável e evolui em raras ocasiões. É nela que tem todo o controle de segurança, *garbage collector*, manipulação de exceções, o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101), controle de *threads*, etc.

Até existia um Visual Studio C# 2010, por exemplo. Ele é o Visual Studio específico para o C# (pelo menos uma forma de usar). Mas a linguagem não chama C# 2010.

[Documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

A pergunta e a resposta foram inspiradas em [post do Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vale citar que o último padrão ISO do C# parou no 2.0 (ISO/IEC 23270:2006). As versões posteriores são iniciativas da Microsoft.