# Qual a diferença entre Visual Basic e Basic?

Tags: vb.net, característica-linguagem, basic

Ouvi dizer que:

> **Visual Basic** é o compilador e **Basic** é a linguagem

Afinal, com as mais recentes tecnologias do .NET, estou programando em Basic ou Visual Basic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC)<sup>*</sup> é uma linguagem criada originalmente em 1965 para simplificar um pouco o desenvolvimento de programas (mal podíamos chamar de aplicações naquela época, ainda que tecnicamente fossem) e quem sabe permitir que estudantes em áreas científicas pudessem usar essa poderosa e nova ferramenta que era o computador.

Hoje é comum chamar esse BASIC original de Dartmouth BASIC. BASIC sozinho indica uma família de linguagens, não é uma linguagem em si. As vezes nos referimos como dialeto de BASIC, mas na prática são linguagens diferentes. Então não é tão fácil dizer no que está programando, se é uma linguagem ou um dialeto, eu vou dizer que é uma linguagem diferente chamada Visual Basic ou VB.NET, ambas da família de linguagens BASIC, mas não é o BASIC em si. Não vou brigar com quem diga que é um dialeto, só não pode dizer que é tudo a mesma coisa. Note que geralmente, na maioria das fontes, são referidos como linguagens diferentes, não só dialeto, a não ser algum caso que seja realmente só um dialeto compatível (raramente um dialeto dura muito, logo ele muda algo que o torna uma linguagem independente).

Hoje toda linguagem da família BASIC deveria ter um nome mais específico. As linguagens da família criadas mais recentemente pela Microsoft (não falarei das mais antigas que ela criou também ou da que foi homenagem a ela, ou da experimental que nunca deram suporte) tem nome e sobrenome: Visual Basic e VB.NET (originalmente chamada de Visual Basic .NET), duas linguagens diferentes.

[Compilador não entra na questão, é outra coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101). Existe um compilador de Visual Basic e outro de VB.NET (atualmente compartilhando infra com C#).

Dá para chamar de Visual Basic o IDE? Dá, mas não chamamos, o nome dele é Visual Studio. Existe uma forma dele com tudo o que é necessário para esta plataforma de desenvolvimento que pode ser chamada de Visual Basic, e até era em certa época, mas não é o nome oficial do IDE. Porém dá margem para interpretação. Isso é [parecido com Delphi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101695/101).

E pode ver mais a [nomenclatura correta para C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101), VB.NET segue a mesma linha. Note (abaixo) que oficialmente o nome do produto inclui o nome da empresa, assim como ocorre com o editor de texto, planilha e outros produtos da gigante de Seattle. Em quase todos os lugares o nome da empresa não é usado. O termo "clássico" é usado, ou era, informalmente para indicar que não é o VB.NET.

[image: Logo e nome do Microsoft Visual BASIC 6.0]

Note outro ponto. A linguagem pode ser tão diferente de BASIC que eles nem continuaram adotando o acrônimo e preferiam ir para a palavra traduzida para um significado de "linguagem básica".

Na minha concepção, com margem para questionamento, você está programando ou em Visual Basic, ou se for com .NET, em VB.NET, o resto seria "liberdade poética". Você adotou uma linguagem da família BASIC.

## Famílias

Outras famílias amplas e conhecidas são [xBase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBase), [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lisp-family_programming_languages) e [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pascal_programming_language_family) (algumas pessoas colocariam [Modula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Modula_programming_language_family) ou [Oberon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Oberon_programming_language_family) como sendo da mesma família).

Existe uma [família de linguagens VB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_(classic)#Derivative_languages) :D

Existem outras menos conhecidas e organizadas, até [Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)) existe.

De uma certa forma quase todas as linguagens atuais são da ["família" Algol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Algol_programming_language_family). Mas isso é forçar bem o que é uma família.

Exemplo da família C, porque até existe, mas é bem pequena, a maioria das linguagens que são ditas assim, na verdade são no máximo C-*like*, ou seja, tem `;` e `{}`, isso não a torna da mesma família, portanto [não confie na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-family_programming_languages). C e C++ possuem dialetos por chaves do compilador, de tão diversos que nem nome possuem. É possível programar virtualmente em infinitos dialetos dessas linguagens, especialmente em C++.

Python 2 e Python 3 acho que são mais dialetos da mesma linguagem. Mas PyPy ou Cython, IronPython e outras já acho que são linguagens, então existe uma família também.

COBOL tem compiladores tão diferentes que já pode ter família e não só dialetos.

Teríamos que questionar o que é dialeto na programação, mas não cabe discutir isso aqui. Por isso tem grande chance [dessa lista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BASIC_dialects) já ter título errado.

Eu não colocaria Kotlin na família de Java, mas não é um absurdo também. O mesmo para Scala, menos ainda Groovy.

Não confundir com [linguagens completamente diferentes que rodam na mesma plataforma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages). Ou [por alguma característica delas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-oriented_programming_languages), ainda que isso pode ser até questionado.

Para não ficar colocando todas as famílias, fica uma [referência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_(classic)#Derivative_languages) que pode ser atualizada, inclusive de forma errada, como está cheio já, mas é uma base para pesquisar melhor e tirar melhores conclusões do que os autores dessas listas.

## Referências confiáveis

Aqui vou fazer parênteses para falar da Wikipedia e outras referências em português. O conteúdo na nossa língua geralmente é ruim e está errado, por isso em questões mais técnicas você tem que procurar a língua mãe, que pode ser diferente em cada domínio. Pode ser o francês para gastronomia, ou inglês para quase tudo. Tem que saber a língua e se orientar por essas fontes, canônicas, oficiais, confiáveis, quando disponível. É necessário senso crítico.

Mesmo em inglês tem muita coisa errada na internet e até mesmo outras fontes como livros ou a documentação oficial. A Wikipedia é um lugar para achar muito erro. A dinâmica dela incentiva erros se perpetuarem, então tem que ter cuidado. Não vou tentar arrumar porque sei como é complicado fazer isso por lá, especialmente a pt. Se o erro foi colocado você tem que provar de forma muito forte para arrumar, mesmo que para colocar o erro não exigiram prova alguma. Ainda mais difícil quando o erro apenas é induzido para você, como é o caso do nosso exemplo.

Nesse verbete a Wikipedia em português começa bem, mas aí se enrola e inventa algo, ainda que fosse com boa intenção e tivesse algum fundo de verdade.

[Em inglês o verbete é melhor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_(classic)).

<sup>*</sup>Ao contrário da crença popular o nome não é por ser uma linguagem básica, ainda que a intenção seja dar um pouco essa conotação. O nome é o acrônimo Beginners All-pourpose Symbolic Instruction Code. Claro, é algo ajambrado para dar o resultado que queriam que é "código de instrução simbólica para todos os propósitos para iniciantes". Por isso esta, como outras linguagens, tal como COBOL, escreve-se em maiúsculo e Java ou Lua escreve-se apenas capitalizada, já que não são acrônimos, mesmo que algumas pessoas escrevam errado, mostrando-se inadequados a serem programadores. Ela era ForTran (melhor escrito assim?) com jeitão de COBOL, porém mais simples.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Alterei a resposta porque essa é mais completa e cita mais fontes. Por mais que algumas do Wikipedia também, pareceu didático e dá para aplicar essa resposta em outras situações parecidas também.

Answer (score 7):

Sua afirmação esta correta segundo o [wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) e wiki de tag [vb](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb)

**Texto da Wiki de Tag VB**

> O Visual Basic (abreviado como VB) é uma linguagem de programação produzida pela empresa Microsoft, e é parte integrante do pacote Microsoft Visual Studio. Sua versão mais recente faz parte do pacote Visual Studio .NET, voltada para aplicações .Net. Sua versão anterior fez parte do Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0, ainda muito utilizado atualmente por aplicações legadas...
>
> Um aperfeiçoamento do BASIC, a linguagem é dirigida por eventos (event driven), e possui também um ambiente de desenvolvimento integrado (IDE — Integrated Development Environment) totalmente gráfico, facilitando enormemente a construção da interface das aplicações (GUI — Graphical User Interface). O nome Visual Basic, é Derivado de:
>
> Basic — a linguagem de Programação
>
> Visual — o Nome do Pacote EX: Visual studio (Visual C++, Visual C#, Visual Basic .NET)

Comment: Legal, o BASIC era da Microsoft desde a criação dele?

Comment: O BASIC não é da microsoft até onde pude pesquisar o Visual Basic sim