# Delphi é uma IDE ou linguagem de programação?

Tags: delphi, ide

Através de uma pergunta que apareceu aqui [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101691/o-que-%C3%A9-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ide-e-compilador), me surgiu uma dúvida:

Delphi é uma IDE ou linguagem de programação? Eu já ouvi programadores que trabalham com Delphi dizer que Delphi é uma IDE utilizada para programar em pascal. Mas qual é a real resposta?

Comment: A pergunta que não quer calar: a pronúncia é *Délfi* ou *Délfai*? :P

Comment: Podemos dizer que Delphi é uma IDE e a versão (depois do 7) do ObjectPascal usada com o compilador do Delphi é uma fork com modificações e acredito que esta fork foi rebatizada de Delphi, assim ambos levam o mesmo nome, semelhante a situação do Webkit (safari) e do Blink (Chrome). Não tenho a fonte desta informação e ela pode ser errônea, mas se eu conseguir irei tentar postar uma resposta :)

Comment: @utluiz é *delfái* :P

Comment: o pascal existe desde 1970, ai vem o Delphi 35 anos depois e utiliza a linguagem e seu compilador, faz umas modificações, e a linguagem passa a se chamar Delphi? Ava

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vai no sebo veja se acha a biblia do delphi 6 e 7 :P pode ter alguma resposta ou dica.

Comment: @EduardoSeixas Acho que Pascal é uma coisa e ObjectPascal é outra. E pelo que estou lendo, na verdade parece que a linguagem é ObjectPascal e foram os usuários que começaram a dar este nome, o problema é que eu não encontre fonte oficial.

Comment: @rray Se isso for sério eu vou procurar kk, se bem que revistas antigas podem ter muita informação errada. O site deles carece de fontes (um wiki).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é serio mesmo, nos primeiros capítulos deve ter essa informação, acredito eu.

Comment: @utluiz Depende de qual país voce esta... [veja](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Pronunciation)

Comment: @utluiz Parece que a grande maioria utiliza [Delfi](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/32261)

Comment: Para ajudar mais um pouco a questão da pronúncia: https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/delphi.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Há controvérsias, eu já vi fontes que alegam uma coisa ou outra.

Isso tem pouca importância prática mas vale a curiosidade, ainda mais porque ajuda [entender um pouco melhor o que está se fazendo e usando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101). Curiosidade é uma característica de todo bom programador, ou talvez qualquer profissional qualificado.

[Object Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Pascal) é uma linguagem originalmente criada pela Apple para melhorar o que o Pascal fazia, e um dos objetivos era adicionar capacidade de lidar com orientação a objeto.

A linguagem criada pela Apple nunca foi padronizada e foi abandonada. A Borland que tinha o melhor produto em cima da linguagem Pascal, o Turbo Pascal, usou a criação da Apple para melhorar seu produto que foi usado como base pela Apple. Depois ela mesma foi melhorando o tal do Object Pascal, se distanciando do que a Apple havia criado.

Em determinado momento não dava mais para chamar aquilo de Object Pascal e o nome da linguagem mudou para Delphi, confundindo com o nome do IDE. O que todo mundo já fazia. O que aumenta a confusão que as pessoas têm sobre o que é linguagem de programação e IDE. Mas o próprio [site da Embarcadero](https://www.embarcadero.com/br/products/delphi) chega usar o termo Object Pascal ainda. Note que em nenhum momento eles tentam resolver a questão. Parece que o termo exato foi escolhido para não deixar claro o que é linguagem e o que é IDE. No fim Delphi talvez seja o pacote todo da linguagem, IDE e outras ferramentas com as bibliotecas.

Pelo menos é isto que diz [essa fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699788/object-pascal-vs-delphi). E a [Wikipedia confirma (ou foi usado de fonte) de alguma forma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(programming_language)) como sendo uma linguagem que é um dialeto do Object Pascal. O [outro artigo dá mais informações](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Pascal).

Há o [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/) que é compatível com Delphi e pode ser usado em diversas plataformas gratuitamente. Não é exatamente a mesma coisa, é muito semelhante.

Delphi é marca registrada da Embarcadero, atual detentora do produto.

O mais importante é que você pronuncie corretamente *delfái* :P

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Recentemente a Embarcadero foi adquirida pela Idera. O produto(IDE) há alguns anos passou a chamar RAD Studio. O compilador(32bits) é dcc32.exe, por sua vez, a versao 64 é dcc64.exe

Comment: Já sobre o nome, quando a IDE é instalada, pode-se instalar suporte à C++ e Delphi. Podemos assumir que é oficialmente Delphi

Answer (score 16):

Pelo que encontrei até agora, atualmente Delphi é uma linguagem de programação, conforme e[sse link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Language_Overview) da embarcadero/borland.

> Delphi is a high-level, compiled, strongly typed language that supports structured and object-oriented design.

[Essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15699788/1342547) do SOen, ajuda a contar parte da história, até a versão 6 o Delphi era uma IDE para object pascal, como a linguagem foi descontinuada pela Apple, a partir da versão 7, a borland pegou o que tinha do object pascal fez algumas modificações e passou a chamar de linguagem Delphi.

Answer (score 12):

Delphi de fato é uma IDE para programação de Pascal.

Mas não só isso, também serve de compilador para a mesma linguagem. Então, além de IDE é um compilador para programadores Pascal.

É muito utilizado no desenvolvimento de aplicações desktop. Aplicações multicamadas e cliente/servidor, compatível com os bancos de dados mais conhecidos do mercado.

Se alguem lhe perguntar em que linguagem você programa, não diga "DELPHI" voce só deve dizer DELPHI, quando lhe perguntarem em qual ambiente de desenvolvimento voce trabalha ou com qual ferramenta voce desenvolve. Quando você está usando o DELPHI, a linguagem gerada por ele é o Object Pascal.

Artigo interessantes sobre Delphi. [O que é Delphi](http://blog.scriptseguro.com.br/o-que-e-delphi/)

Se souber inglês, aqui vai [um artigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_%28programming_language%29) interessante sobre Delphi.

Comment: Não é o que esse artigo diz http://www.clipatecinformatica.com.br/2012/04/delphi-linguagem-de-programacao-ou-ide.html

Comment: Já esse fala que é ide http://blog.scriptseguro.com.br/o-que-e-delphi/

Comment: Exato, alguns dizem que é e outros que não, me parece mais simples para a resposta dizer que é uma IDE.

Comment: Já esse aqui diz as duas coisas: https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/745/conhecendo_o_delphi

Comment: Também acho que é linguagem e IDE, linguagem baseada em object-pascal.

Comment: eu acho que esses "eu acho" acabam gerando a tal discussão

Comment: +1 Ao autor da resposta aqui mais um adicional para a resposta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_%28programming_language%29

Comment: Adicionarei a resposta.

Comment: Não tem nenhum referência da embarcadero/boarland?

Comment: @rray, não achei nada muito produtivo, se tiver algo e quiser adiconar a resposta, fique a vontade. :)

Comment: http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/delphi/delphi.html artigo publicado pela universidade de michigan. Essa questão é muito polêmica.

Comment: Todo mundo sabe que Delphi é IDE, ai ficam colando links para blogs de gente que sabe menos que agente.

Answer (score 5):

Qual compilador Object Pascal que compila essas instruções (generics) se não for o Delphi ?

```
Var
    List : TList<String>; 
Begin
    List : TList<String>.Create; 
End;
```

Qual compilador Object Pascal que compila Métodos Anônimos ?

Qual compilador Object Pascal que compila Class Helpers ?

Qual compilador Object pascal que compila Class Attributes e a insere na RTTI ?

E da forma e na sintaxe que faz o Delphi ?

Diferentemente do Eclipse que possibilita edição de PHP, JAVA e outras linguagens permitindo perspectiva, a IDE do Delphi somente se ajusta ao próprio Delphi, então a IDE do Delphi é própria para ele mesmo, não podendo ser usada para outras linguagens.

Logo o Delphi é Linguagem + Compilador + IDE

Object pascal é a linguagem que se originou o Delphi, até mais ou menos o Delphi 7, após isso foi chamada de Delphi Language por um tempo, e recentemente a embarcadero voltou a chamar a linguagem de Object Pascal, mas também a chama de Delphi, ou seja parece não haver consenso.

Então não é errado chamar a linguagem de Delphi como também não pode-se taxar como erro chamar de Object Pascal de onde tudo se originou.

Comment: excelente resposta +1

Answer (score 4):

Miguel, Delphi é uma IDE usada para criar programas nativos para plataforma windows. A história dessa IDE é longa, existem centenas de capítulos. Eu tenho comigo que a história da informática (como um todo) é bastante extensa, e uma das ferramentas mais usada no mundo é o DELPHI. As informações são tantas, são tantas modificações com o passar dos anos, o sentido se perde se não houver um a resposta bem pensada. o Delphi foi lançado em 1995, são 20 anos de história e inovação, hoje ele é completamente diferente do que já foi. Tome note, considere o Delphi como IDE, (e também como RAD), e seja feliz.

Answer (score 0):

Como alguns já falaram, Delphi atualmente é linguagem de Programação, como se fosse um fork do Object Pascal, quem nomeia a linguagem é o desenvolvedor e mantenedor da linguagem e eles chamam de Delphi.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Delphi_Language_Guide_Index

Answer (score -3):

Vou programar usando a "linguagem de programação Delphi". Opa! Mas isso é um Pascal com algumas melhorias!

Pode chamar do que for, pra mim ainda é Pascal. Até em respeito aos que criaram a linguagem.

Comment: Acho melhor chamar de ALGOL, afinal o Pascal é só ALGOL com algumas melhorias. Deveria respeitar os criadores de ALGOL.