# Tecnologia, Plataforma e Linguagem, o que são e como se relacionam?

Tags: terminologia, ciência-da-computação

Tecnologia, Plataforma e Linguagem são termos usados para caracterizar vários "aspectos" do "mundo da programação".

A quê cada um deles se refere exactamente?
O que os une e/ou os separa?

Comment: Relacionada: [Afinal, Java é uma tecnologia ou uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266489/afinal-java-é-uma-tecnologia-ou-uma-linguagem-de-programação)

Comment: @vnbrs Foi essa pergunta que me levou a fazer esta.

Comment: Plataforma é bem ambíguo, mas com certeza é respondível :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Linguagem

Vou falar mais da [linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101), mas há outras linguagens que usamos na computação.

A linguagem em si é apenas uma [especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101). Normalmente só podendo ser usada quando tem uma implementação feita, tipicamente com um [compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101) e um código de *runtime*, que pode incluir uma biblioteca básica específica. Veja [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101).

A linguagem é o que permite expressar algoritmos e estruturas de dados para que o computador depois saiba o que fazer. Ela é uma formalização de sintaxe (ortografia e gramática) e semântica de instruções que determinarão a execução de um algoritmo.

A linguagem é abstrata demais. Você não instala a linguagem, você simplesmente a usa. Imagino que algumas pessoas devem achar, erroneamente, que o compilador é a linguagem. Além de ser só a implementação, ele sozinho não pode ser considerado a linguagem, precisando de outras partes, por isso imagino também que no contexto o termo esteja sendo usado quase como plataforma.

## Tecnologia

A linguagem é uma tecnologia, o compilador é uma tecnologia, vários outros componentes usados em conjunto são tecnologias. Enfim, quase tudo o que o ser humano criou para resolver problemas é tecnologia. É um conjunto de técnicas, habilidades, métodos e processos para produzir algo com algum objetivo. É conhecimento. Tecnologia é o que te dá capacidade fazer algo.

É um termo bastante amplo e abstrato, que significa pouca coisa ou nada na nossa área. Em geral falamos de ferramentas em geral, softwares ou hardwares que executam alguma tarefa específica, mas tecnologia é muito mais que isso. Usamos o termo para referenciarmos produtos que foram criados para ajudar na criação dos nossos softwares.

Uma linguagem é uma tecnologia, uma plataforma é uma tecnologia, um compilador é uma tecnologia, um *runtime é uma tecnologia. Cada um deles está cheio de tecnologias específicas isoladas ou em conjunto.

Tecnologias específicas vão recebendo outros nomes mais específicos.

Taxonomia é hierárquica, tudo tem vários nomes dependendo do grau de especificidade que deseja designar aquilo. Quando chamamos algo de objeto é uma taxonomia em nível alto.

## Plataforma

Plataforma é algo que sustenta uma série de coisas para alcançar um objetivo. Qualquer coisa que seja usado como base para executar um software dentro de determinadas regras que o software precisa se conformar é uma plataforma. Pode ser um hardware ou software (geralmente são máquinas virtuais ou mesmo sistemas ou ambientes operacionais ou até uma biblioteca, ou ainda navegadores web ou de outro padrão com objetivos semelhantes).

Nenhum software roda se conformando com várias plataformas de forma direta. Ou precisa de outra camada, que acaba sendo outra plataforma em um nível mais alto ou ele precisa ficar verificando a plataforma e tomando decisões sobre o que executar para se conformar como o que está rodando em cima (tem diversas técnicas para isto, todas com penalização de desempenho).

Mas também usamos o termo em um nível mais alto, mais "administrativo", que eu acho que não é o foco. Mas algumas plataformas desse tipo acabam também sendo plataformas de execução também.

É possível ter alguns níveis de plataforma (do mais concreto ao mais abstrato). Em geral só precisa se preocupar mais com o nível mais alto que está mais próximo do seu software. Você não usa a plataforma web tendo que saber como resolver o o acesso a um arquivo, a plataforma abstrai isso. Você não faz um código nativo se preocupando como acessa o teclado.

Não confundir com um [*framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101). Um *framework* é uma tecnologia que roda em cima de uma plataforma e geralmente em conjunto com uma linguagem. É uma forma concreta de acessar a plataforma.

[image: Plataforma/framework]

Como exemplo temos a [Common Language Infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) (CLI). É uma plataforma, e geralmente [apelidamos ela de .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184716/101). Mas essa é apenas uma das implementações dessa plataforma. [Pode ser útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101).

[Outro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230192/101).

## Conclusão

Não considere esta como resposta absoluta, não conheço definição formal dos termos para nossas áreas. Cada pessoa pode classificar as coisas de forma diferente.

Além disso não dá para passar toda a complexidade de classificação disto aqui, a pessoa tem que ir obtendo diversas informações para ir formando uma base que lhe permita entender corretamente.

É frequente que até os criadores de certos produtos chamem uma coisa de forma errada, seja porque ele desconhece ou usa outra definição, seja por puro marketing. O que [frequentemente gera confusão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101695/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Pretendo alterado o título da pergunta para "Tecnologia, Plataforma e Linguagem, o que são e como se relacionam?". A alteração expressa melhor o que pretendo perguntar. Apesar de considerar que a sua resposta vai nesse sentido não queria fazer a alteração sem que se manifeste a favor.

Comment: Pode fazer sim, espero já já dar uma melhorada ou finalizá-la, aí com a mudança já acerto alguma coisa pra adequar.