# O que significa "Dim" em Basic?

Tags: vb.net, terminologia, característica-linguagem, visual-basic-6, basic

`DIM` é usado para declarar variáveis. É notável que ela é uma abreviação, mas, é uma abreviação de quê palavra?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Resumidamente, é um termo que originalmente foi criado para declaração da dimensão de arrays e com o tempo foi sendo usado para outros objetos.

A referência mais antiga que conheço provém do BASIC onde DIM significa "dimension".

Era usado especificamente para determinar a dimensão de um array.

Com o tempo o uso ficou mais abrangente e passou a ser usado também para outros tipos de variáveis. Por isso, o significado original "dimension", atualmente não é intuitivo considerando a finalidade de uso para declaração de tipos diversos e não somente arrays.

Há tentativas de novas interpretações como "declare in memory", devido ao fato de que, com o uso do DIM nas declarações, o objeto é alocado num espaço na memória. Mas o sentido original é "dimension", conforme citado acima.

Comment: E o ReDim é utilizado para redimensionar um array em tempo de execução.

Comment: @cantoni poderia ser "Resize Dimension", ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Certamente é isso @CypherPotato. :-)

Comment: Possivelmente "redimension".

Answer (score 7):

O [`Dim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243352(v=vs.60).aspx) tem múltiplos significados atribuídos à ele, sendo o mais aceito e mais antigo o *dimension*.

#### Dimension

> [DIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmouth_BASIC#List_of_BASIC_statements) — (abreviação de *dimension*) define o tamanho das `arrays`.

O **conceito original** do `Dim` é uma abreviação para *dimension*, vez que nos primórdios do Basic ele era usado somente para definir a dimensão de `arrays`.

Hoje em dia sabe-se que o `Dim` é usado para declarar qualquer variável, portanto este conceito não cabe mais nos dias atuais, o que levou a outras interpretações para `Dim`.

#### Declare In Memory/Module

> [DIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmouth_BASIC#List_of_BASIC_statements) — (abreviação de *declare in memory/module*)

Existem [fontes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/VBLANG/VBLANGVBLangRef67.html) que dizem que o `Dim` significa *Declare In Memory/Module*. Esta referência também é bastante citada, já que foi documentada pela Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

## TL; DR

Dim vem de Dimension - que originalmente era usado dizer quais seriam as dimensões de uma matrix e hoje serve para declarar variáveis em geral, em boa parte das variantes de BASIC existentes. Ela se tornou bastante complexa com inúmeras variações, por exemplo [no VB.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

## Explicando melhor

[BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC)<sup>*</sup> é uma linguagem criada originalmente em 1965 para simplificar um pouco o desenvolvimento de programas (mal podíamos chamar de aplicações naquela época, ainda que tecnicamente fossem) e quem sabe permitir que estudantes em áreas científicas pudessem usar essa poderosa e nova ferramenta que era o computador. Portanto havia uma clara intenção de popularizar a programação, então tinha que ser mais fácil programar que outras linguagens, exigir menos burocracia, ser mais próxima da língua humana, mas poder ser interpretada em computadores de baixa capacidade.

Para facilitar a interpretação optou-se que todas as instruções de código começassem com um comando (exceto operações diretas em variáveis). Para declarar uma variável precisava de um comando. Para facilitar entender o tipo de declaração optou-se em usar `LET` para variáveis escalares e `DIM` para o único tipo composto existente na época que era o *array*.

Como a ideia era ser capaz de fazer operações matemáticas, o tipo de aplicação mais comum na época, e matrizes eram muito comuns, portanto, esses *arrays* tinham potencial de ter dimensões, mesmo que apenas uma, optou-se por usar o termo *dimension*. Poderiam usar outro termo como `ARRAY` ou `MATRIX`, mas essa foi a escolha, talvez por ser mais fácil abreviar para poucas letras (era muito comum em BASIC fazer isso provavelmente para ocupar menos memória, muito necessário na época).

Note que no início escrevia-se tudo em maiúsculo, como geralmente eram as linguagens na época. Apenas em dialetos posteriores aceitou-se escrever de outra forma.

BASIC original (Dartmouth) não se usa mais, tudo o que se vê por aí hoje em dia chamado de BASIC é um dialeto, mas na prática é outra linguagem e há incompatibilidade entre elas, é quase uma sacanagem chamar de BASIC. Elas são tão parecidas quanto C e C# são, ambas são "C" (ah, tá), até no nome. Dá pra perceber? [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/65590/101).

Em alguns desses dialetos permitiu-se criar outros tipos de objetos compostos, o equivalente a uma classe por exemplo. Para não criar uma nova palavra-chave, o que quebraria alguns códigos existentes, optou-se por usar a mesma para esses novos tipos de objetos a serem declarados. Visual Basic e VB.NET são alguns desses dialetos.

Mesmo que algumas pessoas tentem ressignificar o termo, e se fosse um acrônimo o certo seria continuar em maiúsculo, ele é uma declaração de um objeto.

Poderia usar só o `LET` para qualquer tipo de variável? Poderia, mas provavelmente sentiram alguma dificuldade em fazer isso no interpretador, que tinha que ser simples na época, e optaram po isso. Sinceramente, nos dialetos, e acho que alguns até optaram por isto, eu passaria aceitar o `LET` para tudo e, eventualmente, deixar o `DIM` ou `Dim` como compatibilidade. O VB(.NET) fez o contrário, adotou o `Dim` e abandonou o `Let` inicialmente ([hoje ele é usado com LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/queries/let-clause)).

Pelo menos nas primeiras implementações de BASIC usar um `DIM` era reservar memória estática e não no *heap* (geralmente só existia memória global e não local). O `LET` (não costuma valer para *string* que no fundo é um *array*) seria mais na pilha, quando a implementação tinha pilha. Hoje em dia o `DIM` costuma implicar estar no *heap*, por isso pode ainda fazer algum sentido haver uma separação, mas deveria ser bem documentado e principalmente ser consistente. Na prática o `DIM` é que foi oficializado como universal para declarar variáveis quaisquer. E hoje para declarar algo global costuma ser necessário usar um `STATIC` ou `SHARED`.

> Declares and allocates storage space for one or more variables.
>
> `Dim finished As Boolean`
>
> `Dim monitorBox As System.Windows.Forms.Form`
>
> -- [Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

Portanto não é mais para *arrays*.

Você pode interpretá-lo como quiser, pode pensar em *Declare Na Memória* ou só um *DIMensione um objeto na aplicação*, porque declarar uma variável é isso, é dizer qual é o tamanho, é fazer o dimensionamento do espaço que o objeto contido ali precisa. Não importa, poderia usar a palavra XPTO, basta saber a regra e o que essa instrução faz. `DIM` por si só beira uma instrução de Assembly, é um mnemônico sem muito significado intuitivo.

Para completeza, existem outras instruções que declaram variáveis, como um `FOR` por exemplo.

<sup>*</sup>Ao contrário da crença popular o nome não é por ser uma linguagem básica, ainda que a intenção seja dar um pouco essa conotação. O nome é o acrônimo Beginners All-pourpose Symbolic Instruction Code. Claro, é algo ajambrado para dar o resultado que queriam que é "código de instrução simbólica para todos os propósitos para iniciantes". Por isso esta, como outras linguagens, tal como COBOL, escreve-se em maiúsculo e Java ou Lua escreve-se apenas capitalizada, já que não são acrônimos, mesmo que algumas pessoas escrevam errado, mostrando-se inadequados a serem programadores. Ela era ForTran (melhor escrito assim?) com jeitão de COBOL, porém mais simples.

Answer (score 2):

Traduzido em português seria uma instrução, ação imperativa do verbo dimensionar.

Seria algo do tipo: dimensione, DIM.