# O que são os parâmetros out e ref

Tags: c#, .net, parâmetros

Pra que serve os tipos de parâmetro `ref` e `out` de um método no C#? Qual a diferença entre os dois? Algum exemplo de uso de cada um.

Comment: Respostas a perguntas como esta estão na documentação. Se, depois de leres a documentação, tiveres alguma dúvida em concreto, pergunta aqui.

Comment: Eu li a documentação, mas agora com as respostas aqui ficou bem mais claro para min.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Simplificadamente um parâmetro normal tem um sentido, ele só vai, o valor do argumento só é enviado para o parâmetro. O `out` também só tem um sentido, mas contrário, ele só passa o valor do parâmetro (o que está dentro do método) para o argumento. O `ref` faz nos dois sentidos. Ele manda um valor do argumento para o parâmetro e devolve o valor do [parâmetro para o argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

Ambos, argumento e parâmetro devem conter o modificador.

## `ref`

O [`ref`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é para passar o argumento por [referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101), ou seja, em vez de passar o seu valor, passa-se um apontador que indica onde está o valor. Desta forma quando o parâmetro tiver alterado seu valor, estará alterando o valor do argumento já que eles estão na mesma posição de memória.

Só faz sentido o seu uso se o argumento tiver um valor. Em geral o parâmetro deve ser mudado dentro do parâmetro, pelo menos isto deve acontecer condicionalmente.

No fundo um parâmetro por referência é um apelido para uma variável já existente em outro contexto.

```
class RefExample {
    static void Method(ref int i) {
        i = i + 44;
    }
    static void Main() {
        int val = 1;
        Method(ref val);
        Console.WriteLine(val);
        // Output: 45
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Ref.cs).

## `out`

O [`out`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) indica que o argumento a ser passado receberá um valor dentro do método. Ou seja, é uma referência também, mas não é passado nenhum valor para o parâmetro, é apenas uma forma de dar saída para um valor. Isto normalmente é necessário porque o `return` só pode ter um valor.

Usando ele o argumento não precisa ter um valor mas o parâmetro precisa receber um valor antes de encerrar a execução do método.

Ele é mais rápido em alguns cenários.

É verdade que é possível retornar uma [`Tuple`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-8?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) parar "agrupar" vários valores. Mas não é muito elegante. Alguns entretanto, preferem assim.

Foi adicionado o [retorno de múltiplos valores no C# 7](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347). Pode fazer isto: `public (bool, int) Metodo(string)`.

```
class OutExample {
    static void Method(out int i) {
        i = 44;
    }
    static void Main() {
        int value;
        Method(out value);
        // value is now 44
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Out.cs).

O [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) é um dos melhores exemplos de uso. Ele retorna um booleano indicado se o *parse* foi bem sucedido e no parâmetro `out` retorna o valor numérico obtido, se for possível. Se não for possível, nada é retornado nele e não pode ser usado.

## `in`

[Em C# 7.2 existe o `in`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que permite um parâmetro ser recebido como referência igual ao `ref`, porém é garantido que este valor não será alterado, pelo menos pela referência (se tentar modificar usará uma técnica de [COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)). Ele é útil em casos que exige muita performance e não deseja fazer uma alocação no *heap* pressionando o GC. Pense nele como um `ref readonly`.

## Conclusão

C# agora tem o recurso de retornos múltiplos, o `out` não é mais necessário na maioria dos casos. E o `ref` só existe por otimizações, é uma forma de passar dados [por valor como referências](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101). O mecanismo interno do `out` é igual ao do `ref` mas o compilador pode otimizar o código e evitar a passagem do valor.

Note que tipos que são por referência (um `List`, por exemplo, ou qualquer tipo criado com `class`), já são passados como se fosse `ref` (simplificadamente falando, o mecanismo de como é tratado é um pouco diferente internamente).

É necessário tomar cuidado com o uso do `ref` em cenários de concorrência.

Se quiser uma explicação bem detalhada tem um [excelente artigo do Jon Skeet](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html).

Comment: A grosso modo, poderia comparar eles com ponteiros então? Porém com algum refinamento quanto a forma de uso, é isso?

Comment: @bruno101 sim, até porque internamente são ponteiros, só há uma capa que facilita entender e provê restrições úteis para seu melhor uso.

Comment: @Maniero a partir de qual versão o retorno múltiplo está presente no C# ?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 não lembro bem, 7 e alguma coisa, eu costumo tratar como 7, ainda que não seja a 0.

Comment: @Maniero Como assim 7 se a última versão foi a 4.8 ? Poderia ser mais claro ?

Comment: A última versão é 8, e já está para sair a 9. Leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101.

Comment: Oi pessoal, queria avisar que já saiu o C# 12 ok?

Answer (score 9):

Parâmetros **ref** são alterados no local de chamada. Eles são passados como referências, não valores. Isto significa que você pode atribuir o parâmetro no método chamado e tê-lo também ser atribuída no local de chamada.

A palavra-chave **out** força os argumentos a serem passados por referência. Isso é como a palavra-chave referência, exceto que ref requer que a variável seja inicializada antes de ser passada. Para usar um parâmetro com out, a definição do método e a chamada do método devem explicitamente usar a palavra-chave out. Por exemplo:

Out

Segue os exemplos:

```
static void Main()
{
    string value1 = "gato"; 
    SetString1(ref value1); //Passando value1 como referência
    Console.WriteLine(value1); 

    string value2; // String sem atribuição
    SetString2(1, out value2); // Passando value2 como out
    Console.WriteLine(value2); 
    }

    static void SetString1(ref string value)
    {
    if (value == "gato")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("É gato");
    }
        value = "cachorro"; // Atribui novo valor ao parametro
    }

    static void SetString2(int number, out string value)
    {
    if (number == 1) 
    {
        value = "um"; // Atribui o parametro out
    }
    else
    {
        value = "outro valor"; // Atribui o parametro out 
    }
}
```

Saídas:

É gato

cachorro

um

Referências:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/ref

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee332485.aspx