# Erro: uma propriedade ou um indexador que não possa ser passado como um parâmetro out ou ref

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis, parâmetros, referência

Estou com dúvida sobre o **Erro CS0206 Talvéz uma propriedade ou um indexador não possa ser passado como um parâmetro out ou ref** na linha 39 e 41 de meu código, como faz para resolver isso?

```
35| produtos[i] = new Produtos();
...
38| Write($"Digite o preço do {i}º produto : ");
39| if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out produtos[i].Preco)) return 1; x
40| Write($"Digite a quantidade do {i}º produto: ");
41| (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out produtos[i].Quantidade)) return 1; x
```

Comment: isso não pode `out produtos[i].Preco` você precisa passar um variável que não pode ser uma propriedade ... solução rápida `if (decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out  var p)) { produtos[i].Preco = p; }` se passou no teste do TryParse você passa o valor para a propriedade ... Falta contexto, por isso não respondi, não faz sentido colocar um return 1 ali ??? para onde vai retornar 1 ... problemas desconhecidos no seu código, por isso pedi o fechamento pela falta de um contexto para esclarecer todo o código que não foi postado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro é exatamente esse que está escrito, você não pode fazer o que fez. A solução é criar uma variável normal e depois atribuir seu valor para a propriedade que deseja.

Uma variável passada pelo `out` só pode ser uma variável de verdade. Uma propriedade não é uma variável, parece ser uma mas é um método que é chamado para possivelmente acessar uma variável de forma indireta. O modificador `out`, assim como `ref`, acabam tendo uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) e por isso são passadas como um ponteiro e a semântica esperada é que isto seja um ponteiro para um dado de forma direta. Se tiver uma nova indireção o compilador não sabe o que fazer.

Se quiser entender mais sobre como funciona este modificador tem resposta sobre em [O que são os parâmetros out e ref](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101). E para saber mais sobre propriedade tem mais em [Como funcionam as propriedades no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/101) ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/101) e [mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101)). Recomendo fortemente ler estes e outros *links* que dão noção sobre os mecanismos para entender o que está fazendo e não só seguir receitas de bolo.

Então seria algo assim:

```
if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var valor)) return 1;
produtos[i].Preco = valor;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/DecimalTryParse.cs).