# Uso adequado de while para validar entrada de dados

Tags: c#, .net, while, do-while

Estou tentando aplicar uma repetição utilizando o `while` utilizando também da condição IF, que retorna uma mensagem para o usuário caso o mesmo digite um valor inválido. Note que eu nada escrevo dentro do bloco do `while`, mas o código funciona exatamente como eu espero. Apesar disso, o fato de eu não ter colocado nada dentro do `while` me deixa ressabiado, parece que tá errado de alguma forma. Poderiam analisar se é o mais adequado ou se existe uma maneira melhor para resolver situações assim?

```
    string dia;
            string mes;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Em que dia você nasceu?");
                dia = Console.ReadLine();

                if (Convert.ToInt32(dia) > 31)

                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite dia válido");
                }
            }

            while (Convert.ToInt32(dia) > 31);
            {
//repare que aqui eu não escrevo nada
            }

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Em que mês você nasceu?");
                mes = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Convert.ToInt32(mes) > 12)

                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite mês válido");
                }
            }

            while (Convert.ToInt32(mes) > 12);
            {
               //repare que aqui eu não escrevo nada

            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        while (true) {
            WriteLine("Em que dia você nasceu?");
            if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var dia) && dia < 32) break;
            WriteLine("Digite dia válido");
        }
        while (true) {
            WriteLine("Em que mês você nasceu?");
            if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var dia) && dia < 13 break;
            WriteLine("Digite mês válido");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qUz4dV). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RdG8C4). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/MonthDayValidation.cs).

Teste com dados inválidos também.

Está é a forma mais simples e correta de fazer este código. Mesmo que outra forma funcione em um teste rápido, não funcionará em qualquer caso.

Esse laço que está criando é desnecessário e mesmo o código que usou antes é mais complexo do que deveria. Veja que simplifiquei bastante mesmo acrescentando uma validação se o dado foi digitado corretamente. No laço que eu fiz eu testo a validade da digitação, se estiver ok sai do laço, se não passar no teste ele fica repetindo.

[Nunca repita códigos que dizem a mesma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Quando você tem mais de uma vez um mesmo código que é uma regra de negócio corre o risco de em uma manutenção esquecer de mudar o outro. A forma que eu escrevi só tem uma vez a conversão e validação do dado.

Note que este tem erro de lógica. Ele deveria perguntar primeiro o mês de nascimento, e depois o dia. Por que? A validação correta do dia depende do mês que nasceu. Se for janeiro, este código está ok, assim como março, maio, etc. Mas se for em abril, junho, etc. um número 31 é inválido e isso deveria ser pego. Só dá para fazer isso depois que já se sabe qual é o mês. Nem preciso dizer que fevereiro o dia só pode ser até 28 ou 29 se for bissexto.

Claro que se a experiência do usuário pedir para digitar nessa ordem então peça os dois dados e só depois faça a validação.

Fica consertar essa lógica como exercício.

Comment: Cara, que resposta incrível! Vou aplicar essa lógica aqui e vou também fazer o exercício que você propôs. Muito obrigado por elucidar minha questão.

Comment: Se tiver dúvida específica na melhoria que fizer pode postar aqui que ajudamos.

Comment: Para implementar o modificador out no meu projeto github.com/gebueno/MinhaCalculadoraDeSignos eu terei que modificar os métodos que recebem os valores de dia e mes, correto? Tentei a noite toda entender como esse modificador funciona mas não consegui aplicar ao meu projeto.

Comment: @GersonBueno https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101 veja se ajuda. Quase tudo que quer saber tem respondido aqui. Se não tem é oportunidade para fazer uma pergunta nova.

Answer (score 2):

Esse "suposto" bloco `while` que você mencionou não faz absolutamente nada, seria igual usar parênteses assim:

```
int x = 1 + 1;  
// ou
int x = (1 + 1);
```

Note que o while é parte do comando `do`, ou seja, as chaves `{ }` não são da estrutura do `while`, elas estão ali sem fazer nada do seu exemplo.

O fato de encerrar o `while` com `;` já indicaria que encerrou a estrutura, e as chaves não pertencem ao comando, mas sugiro estudar melhor a estrutura do `do` e do `while`.

Faria sentido se o comando fosse assim:

```
while (Convert.ToInt32(dia) > 31)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Em que dia você nasceu?");
    dia = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Convert.ToInt32(dia) > 31)

    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digite dia válido");
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar! Esse bloco que você escreveu tenta comparar uma variável que ainda não tem valor, daí dá erro de "variável sem valor atribuído"...

Comment: sim é um exemplo do `while` sem o `do`, a ideia não foi reescrever todo o código mas mostrar onde estava o problema com o `while` ;)