# É mais vantajoso usar "return" de tupla ou um parâmetro "out"?

Tags: c#, .net, parâmetros, return, tupla

Agora que existe as duas formas de retornar um valor de uma função, é sempre vantajoso usar o retorno de tupla, o "novo" recurso, ou ainda tem motivos para usar um `out` ou até mesmo um `ref`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O advento da tupla retirou muito da funcionalidade do `out`, fazendo com que ele se torne mais legado. Porém ele ainda pode ser útil em alguns casos.

Apesar de ser mais intuitivo e elegante usar múltiplo retorno com uma tupla, o `out` é interessante pelo menos quando você quer obrigar o chamador a pegar o valor retornado. O `return` permite o código só descartar o valor, já o parâmetro terá que criar uma variável e receber o valor. Obviamente que se depois o código não fizer nada com a variável não tem o que fazer.

Lembre-se que um método não pode ser marcado como assíncrono se tiver um parâmetro `out` ou `ref`.

A performance da tupla pode ser ligeiramente inferior nos cenários mais típicos, mas há casos que isso pode se inverter. Não deveria ser uma preocupação até que precise do extremo.

Para o geral é melhor:

```
(int x, bool ok) = Resultado();
```

Do que:

```
bool ok;
int x = Resultado(out ok);
```

Como última informação, o comportamento é ligeiramente diferente, já que usando o `out` ou mesmo `ref` se mudar o valor na função chamada, no mesmo momento está mudando na variável da chamadora, porque a variável da chamada é a variável da chamadora por causa da referência usada. Com a tupla isso só aconteça no fim da execução da função. Em alguns cenários isso pode fazer diferença, especialmente com concorrência.

[Ver mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ReturnTupleOrRef.cs).

Comment: Nem sempre tuplas dão certo onde `out` estão. Por exemplo, `T TryParse(string, out T)` é um pattern que dispensa o uso de tuplas.

Comment: Não é que dispensa, é que a tupla não existia na época que este método foi criado, hoje não seria assim.