# Conversão especificada não é válida

Tags: c#, linq, conversão-de-tipo, count

Estou fazendo um consulta com o `LINQ` no `DataTable` nesse trecho do código. Tenho que verificar se já existe um vínculo para pessoa registada na base da dados. A minha consulta utilizando o `LINQ` esta funcionando perfeitamente, o problema esta para armazenar o `query.Count()` em um uma variável do tipo `int`.

Estou utilizando a versão do Visual Studio 2010. Fiz o teste na versão 2013 e funcionou normalmente. O que poderia ser feito para armazenar o valor do `query.Count()` em uma variável do tipo `int` ou para utilizar em `if()`?

```
//Retorna a relação dos Vinculos contida na base de dados 

DataTable PessoasVinculadas = Pessoa.ConsultarPessoasVinculadas(idPessoaReferenciada);
//Procura os registros existentes 
var query = PessoasVinculadas.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("tipo") == TipoVinculo && x.Field<int>("pessoa_referenciada_id")
== idPessoaReferenciada && x.Field<int>("pessoa_vinculada_id") == idPessoaVinculada);
//Conta os registro existentes 
int cont = query.Count();

//Se registro for igual a 0 Adicionar 
if (cont == 0)
{
    //Cria Vinculo 
    Pessoa.Adicionar(TipoVinculo, idPessoaReferenciada, idPessoaVinculada);
}
```

**Solução Sugerida**

```
 var query = PessoasVinculadas.AsEnumerable()
                         .Where(x => x.Field<int>("tipo") == TipoVinculo
                          && x.Field<int>("pessoa_referenciada_id") == idPessoaReferenciada
                          && x.Field<int>("pessoa_vinculada_id") == idPessoaVinculada).ToList();

                        int cont = query.Count;
```

**Mensagem de Exceção :**

```
System.InvalidCastException was caught
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Conversão especificada não é válida.
  Source=System.Data.DataSetExtensions
  StackTrace:
       em System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
       em Gerencial.Formularios.Gestao.Licenca.ImportarPessoaVinculo.<>c__DisplayClass5.<backgroundWorker_DoWork>b__0(DataRow x) na C:\Users\mmurta\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Gerencial\Gerencial\Formularios\Gestao\Licenca\ImportarPessoaVinculo.cs:linha 240
       em System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
       em System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       em System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       em Gerencial.Formularios.Gestao.Licenca.ImportarPessoaVinculo.backgroundWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) na C:\Users\mmurta\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Gerencial\Gerencial\Formularios\Gestao\Licenca\ImportarPessoaVinculo.cs:linha 239
  InnerException:
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com 2010, 2013? Está falando do VS. Mas ele não importa, o que importa é a versão da linguagem ou do .Net que está usando. Veja isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101. Qual é o problema? Não vejo porque funcionaria em uma versão e não na outra.

Comment: desculpe esqueci de mencionar rs , então não sei fiz o mesmo processo não sei o que pode ter de errado nesta conversão .

Comment: E se você por um .ToList() no final dessa query e usar: query.Count, funciona?

Comment: Laerte nein assim funcionou =\

Comment: Ocorre algum erro?

Comment: Fica aparecendo isso  : System.InvalidCastException was caught
  Message=Conversão especificada não é válida.

Comment: Da forma que eu mostrei também dá esse erro @stringnome?

Comment: Sim , você quer que eu poste o erro detalhado ?

Comment: O count já tipo inteiro, por que você está fazendo cast?

Comment: @stringnome Sim, por favor. Coloque o erro completo e o código atual que você está fazendo (mas não apague o que já está na pergunta).

Comment: você que que eu poste o erro de qual  das tentativas ?essa do To.list() já da o erro na query..

Comment: essa do To.list() já da o erro na query

Comment: Seu erro está em `x.Field<int>` e não no `Count()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro que você está tendo não é no `Count`. É aqui:

```
var query = PessoasVinculadas
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<int>("tipo") == TipoVinculo && 
                            x.Field<int>("pessoa_referenciada_id") == idPessoaReferenciada && 
                            x.Field<int>("pessoa_vinculada_id") == idPessoaVinculada);
```

Alguma dessas variáveis não é `int`. Verifique as conversões.

Além disso, o teste pode ser bastante simplificado para:

```
if (!PessoasVinculadas
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Any(x => x.Field<int>("tipo") == TipoVinculo && 
                            x.Field<int>("pessoa_referenciada_id") == idPessoaReferenciada && 
                            x.Field<int>("pessoa_vinculada_id") == idPessoaVinculada))
{
    //Cria Vinculo 
    Pessoa.Adicionar(TipoVinculo, idPessoaReferenciada, idPessoaVinculada);
}
```

O desempenho de `Count` normalmente é inferior ao de [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb343630(v=vs.110).aspx), e você não está querendo contar, exatamente. Você quer saber se não existem registros, então [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb343630(v=vs.110).aspx) se adequa melhor.

Comment: Consegui encontrar o tipo correto utilizando PessoasVinculadas.Rows[index][columnIndex] muito obrigado pela dica !

Answer (score 2):

> O que poderia ser feito para armazenar o valor do query.Count() em uma variavel do tipo int ou para utilizar em if()?

Você pode converter sua consulta para um lista e usar a propriedade `Count`

```
var count = PessoasVinculadas.AsEnumerable()
                             .Count(x => x.Field<int>("tipo") == TipoVinculo 
                              && x.Field<int>("pessoa_referenciada_id") == idPessoaReferenciada 
                              && x.Field<int>("pessoa_vinculada_id") == idPessoaVinculada);
```

**EDIT**

Seu problema está nos valores dentro `Count()`, algum valor ali não é inteiro, por isso o erro de conversão.

Comment: Tentei mas fica aparecendo  System.InvalidCastException was caught Message =Conversão especificada não é válida.

Comment: Mas você está fazendo algum cast?

Comment: das duas formas que você mencionou deu erro , ele lança a exceção assim que executa