# O que significa # no nome de algumas linguagens?

Tags: c#, f#

Talvez seja a pergunta mais simples possível, mas o que significa o # (sharp) no nome das linguagens C# e F#?

Comment: [Origem do nome no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991345/origin-of-the-c-sharp-language-name)

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Há uma teoria que o C# ganhou este nome (inicialmente a linguagem internamente se chamava [COOL - C-like Object Oriented Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#History)) porque ela seria a evolução do C++, e continuaram a brincadeira de incrementar o nome de C. Então eles fizeram a linguagem C++++, mas empilharam os dois operadores de incremento. Empilhado eles se parecem com `#`.

Já vi outras teorias, como a da nota musical, mas esta parece que foi inventada depois para ter uma estória "melhor".

O F# foi nomeado para indicar que é o C# funcional, afinal ele usa o .NET e segue uma linha semelhante ao C# apesar de ser fortemente inspirado em [OCaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml).

O fato é que isto é apenas uma curiosidade interessante, o nome é o que é.

Tem uma [palestra sensacional](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trHTLFNFoWk) mostrando a trajetória do .NET/C# e alguns bastidores.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. É praticamente impossível pesquisar # no google ou em qualquer outro lugar. ++++  Não posso acreditar q era isso ...

Comment: Tem um fato (pequeno) que favorece a teoria musical: o caracter # é chamado de _hash_, o caracter ♯ é chamado de _sharp_ (sustenido). Note que existem barras verticais, porém não horizontais, no _sharp_, enquanto que no _hash_ existem as horizontais, mas não as verticais. Na hipótese do nome advir da música (meio tom acima de C), a escolha do caracter _hash_ vem de não existir fácil representação do _sharp_ nos teclados comuns.

Answer (score 21):

Em música, C é a notação cifrada da nota ou acorde Dó. [C# seria meio tom acima (Dó Sustenido)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Name). Outra prova disso é [a capa do Deitel sobre C#](http://www-fp.pearsonhighered.com/assets/hip/images/bigcovers/0130622214.jpg), com as formigas e o piano.

Analogamente, F# seria o Fá Sustenido. Não existe uma linguagem F, então a nomenclatura seria congruente apenas ao C#.

Comment: Mas isso é algo oficial ? ou essa capa é feita por terceiros?

Comment: [Segundo o James Kovacs](http://jameskovacs.com/2007/09/07/cnet-history-lesson/), é oficial.

Comment: A sim, naquela época o design era bem ruim...