# Qual a diferença entre usar (int)variavel ou Convert.ToInt32(variavel)?

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo, int, cast

Qual a diferença entre eles? Em que momentos é mais adequado usar um ou outro?

Exemplos:

```
string palavra = "10";
var numero = Convert.ToInt32(palavra); // ou (int)palavra ?

string palavra2 = "10.50";
var numero2 = (double)palavra2; // ou Convert.ToDouble(palavra2) ?
```

Obs: o tipo int só usei como exemplo, mas queria saber de forma geral sobre todos os tipos.

Comment: Quem deu negativo comente o motivo. Se a pergunta não for adequada eu apago ou modifico.

Comment: Não negativei, acho que fica melhor vc colocar o exemplo dos dois na pergunta como código, no título quando li tive a impressão do `(int)` como algo a parte, acho q vc quis dizer: `var num = (int)valor;`

Comment: Valeu @rray, adicionei algum código de exemplo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## *Cast*

O [`(int)`](https://leran.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é um operador de *cast*. Ele só deveria ser usado quando há certeza de que a conversão será bem-sucedida. Também só pode converter valores numéricos. No exemplo, usado o *cast* para `double` não funcionará. Ele não prevê este tipo de conversão.

O *cast* tem que estar disponível para o tipo sendo usado e deve poder manipular o tipo de entrada. É possível criar implementação deste operador para seus próprios tipos, ainda que em poucos casos faça sentido fazê-lo. Ele é menos útil do que parece. E [não tem boa performance em algumas situações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21941/101).

## Convert

O [`Convert.ToInt32()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é um método mais completo que tenta fazer a conversão de forma mais ampla, [podendo usar tipos não numéricos, como *string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#overloads). Obviamente é um método utilitário externo ao tipo.

Em tese estes métodos do `Convert` poderiam fazer um esforço extra para converter objetos que sejam mais difíceis de converter, tentar resolver problemas de conversão de forma mais inteligente. Na prática isto não costuma ocorrer.

Em geral seu uso é adequado quando você sabe que a conversão será bem-sucedida, ou seja, é garantindo que tem um número válido no texto ou quando a fonte para a conversão não é uma *string*.

## Parse

Mas para *string*, quase sempre é melhor [usar um `int.Parse()`, ou melhor ainda, um `int.TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101), afinal se não tem certeza se o valor pode ser convertido [é melhor ter um código de erro do que uma exceção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Ainda existem algumas implicações quando se usa outra linguagem com o .NET. O *cast* faz parte do sistema de tipos, o `Convert` é só uma utilidade extra.

Relacionada: [Qual a principal diferença entre int.Parse() e Convert.ToInt32()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101).

Não deixe de ver: [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 10):

O `(int)variável` é um **cast**, que no caso da sua questão não vai funcionar para String (string), dando essa mensagem de erro:

> CS0030 Cannot convert type 'string' to 'double'

No caso você pode utilizar o `Convert`, mas, hoje em dia utilizamos o `int.Parse` ou melhor ainda `int.TryParse`.

Na verdade o `Convert` não é muito utilizado nos dias atuais por problemas de algumas conversões ...

***Exemplo:***
*ref site e todos os créditos à* [**Convert.ToInt32 vs Int32.Parse - Código Fonte**](https://www.codigofonte.net/dicas/csharp/352_converttoint32-vs-int32parse)

```
string s1 = "1234";
string s2 = "1234.65";
string s3 = null;
string s4 = "1234567891234567891123456789123456789";
```

**Convert**

```
result = Convert.ToInt32(s1); //-- 1234
result = Convert.ToInt32(s2); //-- FormatException
result = Convert.ToInt32(s3); //-- 0
result = Convert.ToInt32(s4); //-- OverflowException
```

**Parse**

```
result = Int32.Parse(s1); //-- 1234
result = Int32.Parse(s2); //-- FormatException
result = Int32.Parse(s3); //-- ArgumentNullException
result = Int32.Parse(s4); //-- OverflowException
```

**Recomendação:**

Utilize sempre os métodos referente as conversões dos tipos
`int`, utilize `int.Parse` ou `TryParse` e assim por diante, trazendo inclusive uma maior clareza no seu código. O `Convert` possui alguns métodos que são utilizados em algum momento em seu código, mas, a frequência é baixa!

Comment: Bacana os exemplos em código.

Comment: O assunto é que é bacana viu, parabéns pelo questionamento, só reforçando utilize em quase sua totalidade o Parse ou TryParse emiti clareza ao seu código e padronização

Comment: @bigown a fonte minha foi retirada do Código Fonte como link descrito na resposta.

Comment: Estou mudando o *link*, porque o original ainda está em outro lugar, espero que a cadeia de cópias/citações não tenha ido além: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32885/Difference-Between-Int32-Parse-Convert-ToInt32-and

Comment: Eu acredito que foram já @bigown