# Qual a principal diferença entre int.Parse() e Convert.ToInt32()?

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo

No C#, existem duas formas (dentre outras) de se converter outros tipos para `int`:

`Convert.ToInt32(valor)` e `Int32.Parse(valor)`.

Qual a principal diferença entre essas duas formas de conversão?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

O [`Int32.Parse(valor)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-6.0) só converte conteúdo vindo de *string*. O [`Convert.ToInt32()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) tem sobrecargas para trabalhar com vários tipos. Esta é a principal diferença.

Mas a melhor forma é ver como ele é internamente:

`Parse()`:

```
public static int Parse(string s)
{
    return System.Number.ParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}

internal static unsafe int ParseInt32(string s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
{
    byte* stackBuffer = stackalloc byte[1 * 0x72];
    NumberBuffer number = new NumberBuffer(stackBuffer);
    int num = 0;
    StringToNumber(s, style, ref number, info, false);
    if ((style & NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) != NumberStyles.None)
    {
        if (!HexNumberToInt32(ref number, ref num))
        {
            throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
        }
        return num;
    }
    if (!NumberToInt32(ref number, ref num))
    {
        throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
    }
    return num;
}
```

`Convert()`:

```
public static int ToInt32(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/ParseToInt.cs).

Retirado [dessa resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201405/221800).

Mas você pode ver o código fonte real: [`Convert.ToInt32()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,fc990bd1275d43d6) e [`Parse()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,a438016f815a35c3). Melhor ainda acompanhar no .NET Core ([`Convert.ToInt32()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Convert.cs,069d595792a157df,references) e [`Parse()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Int32.cs,a438016f815a35c3,references)).

Prefira o [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101)

Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre usar (int)variavel ou Convert.ToInt32(variavel)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90928/101).

Não deixe de ver: [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Comment: Vale a pena observar que o Convert transforma null em 0. Esse pode ser um comportamento indesejado em muitos casos, por exemplo, onde o 0 é informação e null seria a ausência de informação. Nessa situação, tryParse é a opção. Imagine, por exemplo, fazer a média de valores opcionais armazenados em um arquivo de texto, se usado Convert a média será incorreta pois converterá para zero valores que não existem, trazendo a média para um valor inferior ao real...

Comment: Entao deixa eu entender, o convert() aceita converter qualquer valor vindo de qualquer tipo para o inteiro, é isso?

Answer (score 12):

Jogando `Int32.Parse()` no [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/):

```
public static int Parse(string s)
{
    return System.Number.ParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

Que por sua vez, chama:

```
internal static unsafe int ParseInt32(string s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
{
    byte* stackBuffer = stackalloc byte[1 * 0x72];
    NumberBuffer number = new NumberBuffer(stackBuffer);
    int num = 0;
    StringToNumber(s, style, ref number, info, false);
    if ((style & NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) != NumberStyles.None)
    {
        if (!HexNumberToInt32(ref number, ref num))
        {
            throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
        }
        return num;
    }
    if (!NumberToInt32(ref number, ref num))
    {
        throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
    }
    return num;
}
```

Jogando `Convert.ToInt32()` no Reflector:

```
public static int ToInt32(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

## Uso

- `Int32.Parse()` é visivelmente mais rápido que `Convert.ToInt32()`, mas mais insegura. Você deve usar `Int32.Parse()` quando tem certeza que o valor de entrada é um inteiro;
- Há ainda [`Int32.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx), que é um pouco mais segura. Devolve zero se a conversão falhar e não lança exceção;
- `Convert.ToInt32()` é um envelope um pouco mais seguro de `Int32.Parse()` (dá pra ver pelo código.

## Performance

Ainda, a maneira mais rápida de realizar a conversão é por um simples *cast*:

```
var inteiro = (int)meuObjeto;
```

Claro que é bastante inseguro fazer isso, mas compensa se, novamente, você sabe que o que tem dentro do `object` é um inteiro.

[Por esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/638513/1314276), é possível ver o *assembly* deste *cast*:

```
.locals init (
    [0] object x,
    [1] int32 Y)
L_0000: ldc.i4.1 
L_0001: box int32
L_0006: stloc.0 
L_0007: ldloc.0 
L_0008: unbox int32
L_000d: ldobj int32
L_0012: stloc.1 
L_0013: ret
```

Enquanto que `Convert.ToInt32()` gera:

```
.locals init (
    [0] object x,
    [1] int32 Y)
L_0000: ldc.i4.1 
L_0001: box int32
L_0006: stloc.0 
L_0007: ldloc.0 
L_0008: call object [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::GetObjectValue(object)
L_000d: call int32 [mscorlib]System.Convert::ToInt32(object)
L_0012: stloc.1 
L_0013: ret
```

[Esta resposta tem um *benchmark* completo sobre todos os modos de atribuição possíveis para um inteiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/641658/1314276). A diferença é estrondosa.

Comment: Não é possível fazer *cast* com *string*, então a informação está incorreta e a comparação não faz sentido nesta pergunta.

Comment: Tem razão. Mudei para `object`. Obrigado!

Comment: Ok agora, mas ainda não faz sentido comparar a performance do `Convert` de numérico com `Parse` de *string* . São duas entradas distintas. É como dizer que uma Ferrari é mais rápida que o caminhão, mas estamos querendo saber qual carrega mais carga.

Comment: Não entendi seu pronto. A pergunta é sobre as diferenças entre uma e outra.

Comment: Comparar performance de conversão de numérico com performance de conversão de *string* não tem significado. Elas fazem coisas distintas. De que adianta um ser mais rápido se ele não serve ao propósito?

Comment: Não vi nada escrito especificamente sobre *string* no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: Está implícito. O `Parse` só faz isto.

Comment: Por favor, pare de achar defeito na minha resposta. Isto não está sendo produtivo.

Comment: Seria mais fácil você resolver o defeito, mas se não quer, ok. Pelo menos as pessoas podem saber que há este problema.

Comment: calma pessoal, estamos aqui pra se ajudar.