# Vetor recebe retorno de método

Tags: c#, .net, método

Estou montando um programa em C# e criei um método chamado Fornecimento que recebe um vetor chamado numero e retorna o mesmo. A ideia é que a função fornecimento crie valores aleatórios, preencha o vetor e o devolva preenchido para a função principal(ainda não fiz essa parte de criação de valores), a função está sendo chamada no `Main`.

O problema: está acusando que a linha em que eu chamo o método no `Main` está errada, já tentei de várias formas, mas até agora nada deu certo.

Não sei se declarei certo a linha:

**LINHA DO ERRO - : numero = Fornecimento(numero);**

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {

            /*---------------------------------------------------
                            Métodos do programa
            ---------------------------------------------------*/

            //Método de fornecimento de numeros
            int[] Fornecimento(int[] numero)
            {
                int opcao;
                //apresentação do tipo de opcao
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("*****************************************************************");
                Console.Write("\n*\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t*");
                Console.Write("\n*\t\tFORNECIMENTO DE NUMEROS\t\t\t\t*");
                Console.Write("\n*\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t*");
                Console.Write("\n*****************************************************************");
                Console.Write("\n\n\tO que deseja fazer: \n\n\t=>1-Fornecer os numeros \n\t=>2-Gerar numeros automaticamente \n\n\tEscolha uma opcao: ");
                opcao = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (opcao == 1)
                {

                }

                return (numero);
            }


            /*---------------------------------------------------
                        Método principal do programa
            ---------------------------------------------------*/
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //declaração de variáveis
                int[] numero = new int[500000];
                int retorno = 1, tipo = 0;

                while (retorno == 1)
                {
                    //comando limpa a tela
                    Console.Clear();
                    //apresentação do programa
                    Console.Write("*****************************************************************");
                    Console.Write("\n*\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t*");
                    Console.Write("\n*\t\t\tALGORITMO DE ORDENACAO\t\t\t*");
                    Console.Write("\n*\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t*");
                    Console.Write("\n*****************************************************************");

                    //menu de escolha do tipo de algoritmo de ordenação(loop repete até que um tipo válido seja inserido)
                    while ((tipo != 1) && (tipo != 2) && (tipo != 3))
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n\n\tQue tipo de algoritmo deseja utilizar: \n\n\t1-Inserction sort \n\t2-Selection sort \n\t3-Bubble sort \n\n\tEscolha uma opção=> ");
                        tipo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }

                    numero = Fornecimento(numero);

                }
                retorno++;
                //Environment.Exit(exitCode);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Diz qual é o erro, qual a linha.

Comment: 'numero = Fornecimento(numero);'

Comment: Seu `retorno++;` está fora do `while`por isto não funciona.

Comment: Qual é o erro??

Comment: arrumei mas continua sinalizando erro na chamada do método @Marlon Tiedt

Comment: Há consegui! tinha que por o static na declaração do método

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema na linha específica é que o método `Main()` é estático e o `Fornecimento()` não é, não dá para chamar um método de instância em um método estático. Ambos precisam ser estáticos, então basta colocar um `static` lá no método e este problema resolverá.

Também há o problema que o `Main()` precisa ser público. Depois de arrumar isto vai compilar, mas não executará direito porque o código está cheio de outros erros.

Dei uma melhorada no código, eliminando alguns erros, algumas práticas ruins, modernizei ele. Tem coisa que poderia ficar melhor. Mas cansei :) Aconselho aproveitar isto e as dicas nos comentários para melhorar mais.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    public class Program {
        static int[] Fornecimento(int[] numero) {
//          Clear();
            WriteLine("*****************************************************************");
            WriteLine($"*{new String(' ', 63)}*");
            WriteLine($"*{new String(' ', 16)}FORNECIMENTO DE NUMEROS{new String(' ', 24)}*");
            WriteLine($"*{new String(' ', 63)}*");
            WriteLine("*****************************************************************");
            WriteLine($"\n{new String(' ', 8)}O que deseja fazer: \n\n{new String(' ', 8)}=>1-Fornecer os numeros \n{new String(' ', 8)}=>2-Gerar numeros automaticamente \n\n{new String(' ', 8)}Escolha uma opcao: ");
            int opcao = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine()); //espero que esta variável vá ser usada em outro lugares
            if (opcao == 1) {
                //espero que vá fazer alguma aqui
            }
            return numero;
        }
        
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            int[] numero = new int[500000];
            int retorno = 1, tipo = 0; //tipo precisa ser declarada aqui mesmo? no momen to não
            while (retorno == 1) { //este while não faz o menor sentido
//              Clear(); //por alguma razão aqui dá problema executar, mas pode descomentar isso
                WriteLine("*****************************************************************");
                WriteLine($"*{new String(' ', 63)}*");
                WriteLine($"*{new String(' ', 16)}ALGORITMO DE ORDENACAO{new String(' ', 25)}*");
                WriteLine($"*{new String(' ', 63)}*");
                WriteLine("*****************************************************************");
                while (tipo >0 && tipo < 4) {
                    //isso é muito gambo, o ideal seria fazer cada linha em um comando próprio, arumei um pouco mas desisti de fazer tudo
                    Write($"\n\n{new String(' ', 8)}Que tipo de algoritmo deseja utilizar: \n\n{new String(' ', 8)}1-Inserction sort \n{new String(' ', 8)}2-Selection sort \n{new String(' ', 8)}3-Bubble sort \n\n{new String(' ', 8)}Escolha uma opção=> ");
                    tipo = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine()); //esta convers]ao é insegura, prefira um int.TryParse()
                }
                Fornecimento(numero);
                retorno++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Fr9qaE). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k5K1a8). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/CallStaticMethod.cs).

Sobre o uso do [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101). leia tudo, siga os *links*. Especialmente o [Diferenças entre Parse vs TryParse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101)

Comment: Obrigada é isso mesmo já tinha até visto agora pouco,mas muuuuito obrigada!!

Answer (score 1):

Ajuste o seu código e coloquei o mesmo rodando em: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ADIUxT

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda!!! :)