# Como faço para jogar a variável dentro de um texto em "MessageBox.Show" de uma "case" no comando "switch"?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Estou fazendo uma interface de um programa em `switch` utilizando o C# para saber quais são as bodas de casados de um casal, **só que eu não sei como inserir a variável resultado para a `case default` caso as bodas de casados não sejam 25, 50 e 75 (tipo pode ser 21, 32, 45 anos de casados)**. O que eu deve ser feito para mostrar o valor nessa case caso não atenda as condições anteriores de 25, 50 e 75 anos de casado.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TesteSwitch1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int resultado, ano_atual, ano_casaram;
            ano_atual = Convert.ToInt32(txtAA.Text);
            ano_casaram = Convert.ToInt32(txtAC.Text);
            resultado = ano_atual - ano_casaram;
            switch (resultado)
            {
                case 25:
                    MessageBox.Show("25 anos de casado! BODAS DE PRATA!", "Mensagem");
                break;
                case 50:
                    MessageBox.Show("50 anos de casado! BODAS DE OURO!", "Mensagem");
                break;
                case 75:
                    MessageBox.Show("75 anos de casado! BODAS DE DIAMANTE!", "Mensagem");
                break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("", "Mensagem"); // Aqui que está a minha dúvida
                break;
            }
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtAA.Text = "";
            txtAC.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usei [interpolação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101) para obter o que quer, e aproveitei e consertei um outro erro fazendo a validação da entrada de forma correta evitando que sua aplicação quebre, mas precisa melhorar o tratamento, aí fica com você.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!int.TryParse(txtAA.Text, out var anoAtual || !int.TryParse(txtAC.Text, out var anoAtual) {
        MessageBox.Show("Ano inválido não é possível continuar", "Mensagem");
        return;
    }
    int resultado = anoAtual - anoCasamento;
    switch (resultado) {
    case 25:
        MessageBox.Show("25 anos de casado! BODAS DE PRATA!", "Mensagem");
        break;
    case 50:
        MessageBox.Show("50 anos de casado! BODAS DE OURO!", "Mensagem");
        break;
    case 75:
        MessageBox.Show("75 anos de casado! BODAS DE DIAMANTE!", "Mensagem");
        break;
    default:
        MessageBox.Show($"{resultado} anos de casado", "Mensagem"); // Aqui que está a minha dúvida
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/InterpolationMessageBox..cs).

Note que isto nada tem a ver com Visual Studio (que tinha na versão original da pergunta, com `switch` ou mesmo com o `MessageBox.Show()`, o problema é apenas de manipulação de `string`.

Comment: Tava dando erro, olhei bem e era isso :). Mas por quê aquele if de ano inválido antes do código?

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101 Isto também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101

Comment: Lembrando que: precisa ter o C# 6.0+ para ter suporte às Strings Interpoladas.