# Problemas em quebra de linha e exibir corretamente a conversão de valor real no C#

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, console, conversão

Fiz um código simples de C# que pede para inserir nome, idade, peso, cidade e estado, executa normalmente só que aparece alguns problemas como ao invés do peso ser 60.5KG fica 605KG e queria saber como quebrar a linha para imprimir a parte de preencher o formulário e a impressão de forma separada.

```
// Meu Código
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TerceiroCd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String nomeNome, cidadeC, estadoE;
            double peso;
            int idade;

            Console.Write("Digite o seu nome: ");
            nomeNome = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Digite a sua idade: ");
            idade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Digite o seu peso: ");
            peso = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Digite sua cidade: ");
            cidadeC = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Digite o seu estado: ");
            estadoE = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine($"Seu nome é {nomeNome}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Possui {idade} de idade e pesa {peso}KG");
            Console.WriteLine($"Mora na cidade de {cidadeC} no estado de {estadoE}");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

```
// A impressão fica assim
Digite seu nome: Alex F.
Digite sua idade: 20
Digite o seu peso: 60.5
Digite sua cidade: Guanambi
Digite o seu estado: Bahia
Seu nome é Alex F.
Possui 20 anos de idade e pesa 605KG // Valor errado
Mora na cidade de Guanambi no estado da Bahia
```

```
// Queria que fosse assim:
Digite seu nome: Alex F.
Digite sua idade: 20
Digite o seu peso: 60.5
Digite sua cidade: Guanambi
Digite o seu estado: Bahia

Seu nome é Alex F.
Possui 20 anos de idade e pesa 60.5KG
Mora na cidade de Guanambi no estado da Bahia
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Quebra linha

Coloque um `WriteLine()` onde quer que pule uma linha, assim você manda imprimir nada além de uma quebra de linhas, afinal o método chama Write**Line**.

Também é possível `\n` no texto que é o caractere que faz pular linha.

## Conversão de dados

[Quanto aos `Parse()` vai quebrar sua aplicação quando digitarem algo errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). É bom ler também [Qual a principal diferença entre int.Parse() e Convert.ToInt32()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101) porque a outra resposta comete o mesmo erro.

Note que a pessoa precisa digitar dentro do formato da cultura vigente que a *thread* tem no momento, se nada for especificado então é o que está configurado no sistema operacional. Como deve estar no formato `pt-BR` então deve digitar a vírgula como separador decimal.

Para garantir certo formato é preciso configurar o método de *parse* no formato específico que aceita ou não, então deve usar a assinatura do método mais completo que pede o estilo e a cultura. No caso talvez o estilo `Float` deve resolver a questão e não aceitar o ponto decimal (fiz um teste rápido e deu certo mas precisaria de um teste mais extensivo e melhor avaliação), seria algo assim:

```
double.TryParse("60.5", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var peso)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/TryParseDoubleCulture.cs).

Foi comentado para dar um `Replace()`. Isto é uma enorme gambiarra. Isto não deve ser feito, isto é pedir para ter problemas futuros.

Primeiro, raros os casos que alterar o dado que a pessoa digitou é uma boa ideia. Vou repetir porque sei que todo mundo faz isso: é raro ser uma boa ideia mudar algo que a pessoa digitou, e sim quase todo mundo erra nisto. É até possível em alguns casos você mudar, mostrar para o usuário de uma forma ou de outra o valor modificado e deixar ele confirmar esse dado ou não, a forma exata de fazer isto depende do contexto. Quer fazer ter todo esse trabalho? Se for o caso pode fazer assim usando este padrão.

Você pode fazer uma validação extra e não permitir a entrada do dado neste formato, mas é exatamente o que o comando acima faz. Aí é você dar o tratamento mais adequado para o caso, normalmente o [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Double__) é usado como condição de um `if`, e dentro dele você pode fazer o que quiser, por exemplo pode dar uma dica para o usuário sobre o erro. Infelizmente o `TryParse()´não dá maiores detalhes de qual o erro específico ocorrido, pode ser uma falha dele, mas a forma de resolver isto é fazer seus próprio *parser*, simples ou complexo para achar qual é o erro e dar uma dica mais específica. neste exemplo você pode verificar que está usando uma cultura que exige vírgula como separador decimal e mostrar para o usuário que ele está usando ponto. Dá trabalho, para um caso simples assim eu não faria.

Nesse caso se você trocar o ponto pela vírgula se a pessoa digitar o ponto como separador de milhar ou por qualquer outra razão maluca, se ele colocar coisas aleatórias vai dar um belo problema.

Você quer um sistema robusto ou um que aceite qualquer coisa e quebre? Se quer o segundo, ok, apenas diga para o usuário que ele tem que digitar certo e aceite quando ele digitar errado. Em um sistema real em produção isso não é aceitável. Se quer algo robusto então tem que pensar em todos os casos, não só em alguns.

Existem outras coisas que podem ser simplificadas no código.

Comment: Minha variável peso quando é digitada 60.5 aparece 605 na impressão, como resolve isso?

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir o problema, a aplicação quebra todas as vezes e a resposta já fala nisto.

Comment: Mas o código executa, só tá mostrando o valor do peso de forma errada

Comment: Editei, tem que fazer algo mais pra não aceitar o ponto.

Comment: Se colocar 60,5 vai normal, mas números reais em programação não usam virgula

Comment: Isso não é programação, é entrada de dados.

Comment: Você pode dar um replace no "." e substituir por ",". Exemplo: peso = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Replace(".",","))

Comment: @Lucas isso é gambiarra, é uma forma de ajustar se a pessoa entrar errado, mas gera uma ambiguidade, e se a pessoa usar separador de milhar? As pessoas nunca pensam no uso real. É o que eu sempre falo, as pessoas não querem fazer o certo, querem só ver funcionar, aí alguém faz algo fora do normal e dá problema. è possível até fazer uma análise personalizada e dar uma mensagem para a pessoa indicando que provavelmente ela está digitando errado  como dica para ela entrar o dado de forma correta, mas não como validação, e principalmente não como mudança cumpulsória e automática.

Comment: Neste caso não gera problema. Mas as entradas de dados dele precisam ser validadas corretamente. Poderia fazer isso usando um TryParse

Comment: Gera problema sim, o fato de você não ver problema não quer dizer que não gera, eu escrevi um caso que gera problema.

Comment: @Lucas usando o Replace() deu certo, mas pode ser um problema no futuro.

Comment: qual? Vai gerar problema se digitar uma string alfanumerica. O que pode acontecer nos outros inputs. Mas se validar com um TryParse() da para tratar isso. Qualquer tipo diferente de string pode gerar erro na hora de entrar com um input, é importante validar os tipos de entrada

Comment: @AlexF. Exatamente o que eu falei, deu certo um caso, não todos, https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgk8Q.png

Comment: @Lucas fui tentar tirar a vírgula ficando apenas um ponto, mas a IDE acusou que o Replace() precisa de 2 argumentos para funcionar.

Comment: Sim, o método Replace() usa 2 argumentos. O primeiro indica a string que você quer substituir, o segundo indica a string que ficará no lugar. Caso não encontre a string a ser substituída, não altera nada.

Comment: "Neste caso não gera problema" = gambiarra. Recomendo que pessoas que insistam muito nessa linha de raciocínio tentem algo na área de humanas, tipo artes plásticas, teatro, e outras coisas que dêem espaço para interpretações pessoais. Para exatas é meio arriscado trabalhar assim, prejudica o cliente (melhor mesmo é repensar de maneira mais ampla e melhorar os procedimentos, claro).

Comment: @Maniero, ficou curti a solução, show! Com certeza é melhor deste jeito, mas da outra forma ele não teria problema também, se usasse o TryParse(), conforme você fez.

Comment: @Bacco, obrigado pelo feedback. Tentei apenas ajudar o amigo, esta era a solução que tinha em mente. Agora, aprendi uma nova técnica com o Maniero.

Comment: @Lucas justamente, propor algo que talvez não seja o ideal acontece com bastante frequência e com bastante gente, o que não pode é se contentar com a solução e ficar nisso. Desde que você entenda o problema que aquilo gera e melhore a cada "iteração", tá tudo dentro da normalidade. Óbvio que nas nossas coisas a gente toma liberdade de fazer gambiarra pra resolver problemas imediatos, mas sempre que for ensinar um terceiro é importante deixar bem claro o problema daquilo (ou realmente focar só na maneira técnica adequada mesmo)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Meu Código
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TerceiroCd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String nomeNome, cidadeC, estadoE;
            double peso;
            int idade;

            Console.Write("Digite o seu nome: ");
            nomeNome = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Digite a sua idade: ");
            idade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Digite o seu peso: ");
            peso = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Digite sua cidade: ");
            cidadeC = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Digite o seu estado: ");
            estadoE = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine($"\n Seu nome é {nomeNome}. \n Possui {idade} anos de idade e pesa {Convert.ToString(peso).Replace(",", ".")} Kg. \n Mora na cidade de {cidadeC}, estado de(a) {estadoE}.");

            // Use o \n para quebrar a linha dentro de uma string
            // Ao invés de Parse tente o Convert
            // Ao invés de um ponto tente usar uma virgula ao inserir o peso
            // Replace() => Substitui um caracter por outro

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Teria algum problema seu colocasse **Convert.ToInt16** ao invéz de **Convert.ToInt32**?

Comment: Basicamente, o int 16 = suporta os valores de −32,768 até +32,767, 
int 32 = suporta os valores de −2,147,483,648 até +2,147,483,647,
int 64 = suporta os valores de −9,223,372,036,854,775,808 até +9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: Ainda continua mostrando 605KG ao invés de 60.5KG :(

Comment: A solução que pensei para este caso é o Replace(). Se você validar as entradas certinho, não terá problema com este uso.

Comment: Eu utilizei a virgula ao invés do ponto para inserir o peso, funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Valores reais no C# usam ponto ou vírgula?

Comment: @AlexF. editei a minha, isto não é solução, tentei deixar o mais completa possível. Você ainda não entendeu o que é código e o que é entrada de dados, não misture os conceitos.

Comment: @AlexF. internamente a linguagem não usa nem uma coisa nem outra, o que acontece é que você está com um problema na interface com os dados do usuário. Armazenamento interno é específico da linguagem, no código fonte é outra coisa, usa-se o ponto decimal em praticamente qualquer linguagem comum, sem separador de milhares, e ai vem uma terceira coisa, que é o lugar onde o usuário digita (seja console ou campo gráfico) - Isso  já depende das configurações de linguagem do usuário, no caso do C#, que é justamente a situação prevista na resposta do Maniero.