# Problemas ao utilizar o null coalescing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, datetime

Estou com dificuldade em conseguir usar o *null coalescing* no caso a baixo:

Ao tentar utilizar o operando `??` para validar se o valor vindo no `reader["Data"]` é nulo, e se o for devolver o `DateTime.MinValue`.

O erro que devolve é:

> Operator ?? cannot be apllied to operands of type 'DateTime' and 'DateTime'

```
 using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            vendasConfirmadas.Select(v => new Pedido()
                            {                                    
                                Data = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Data"]) ?? DateTime.MinValue
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

O operador de *null coalescing* só pode ser aplicado em tipos anuláveis, que eram padrão antes do C# 8 para tipos por referência, ou se especificado no tipo em qualquer versão (não podia especificar nos tipos por referência antes do C# 8). O `DateTime` é um tipo por valor, então ele só pode ser nulo se especificado explicitamente, o que não acontece com o `ToDateDatime()`.

Na verdade este código está todo errado se espera que algo dê errado e nem deveria tentar fazer assim, o correto seria:

```
if (!datetime.TryParse(reader["Data"], out var data)) data = DateTime.MinValue;
Data = data;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/TryParse2.cs).

Veja [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) e [Qual a principal diferença entre int.Parse() e Convert.ToInt32()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101), o mesmo vale pra data.

Por outro lado se você puder garantir que o dado está correto aí não precisaria fazer nada, porque [o método `ToDateTime()` retorna exatamente o que deseja se o valor a ser convertido for nulo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_), então para seu caso, se puder garantir isto, e só neste caso, faça a conversão sem usar a operação de verificação de nulo, já que o método nunca retorna nulo.

Comment: Ah, Ajudou Bastante! Obrigado!!

Comment: @DemetriusPecoraro veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.