# CS0747 Erro com declarador C#

Tags: c#, .net, classes, instanciar-objeto

[image: Imagem do erro CS0747]

Criei uma lista que recebe meu objeto comanda alimentado pelos campos do meu forms, minha classe:

```
public class Comanda //Essa classe carrega tudo necessário para o pedido.
{
    public int idComanda { get; set; } //número do pedido, usaremos como chave de busca
    public int nMesa { get; set; }
    public Cliente cliente { get; set; }
    public Produto produto { get; set; }
}
```

O problema talvez esteja aqui, quando crio meus atributos `cliente` e `produto`, eles são do tipo `Cliente` e `Produto`, classes abaixo:

```
public class Cliente:Pessoa
{
    public int idCliente { get; set; }
}
```

`Cliente` herda a classe base `Pessoa`:

```
public abstract class Pessoa //classe base
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string endereco { get; set; }
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    public int telefone { get; set; }
}

public class Produto
{
    public int idProduto { get; set; }
    public string categoriaProduto { get; set; }
    public string nomeProduto { get; set; }
    public string descProduto { get; set; }
    public double valorUnitario { get; set; }
}
```

Sabendo disso, eu instancio ambos os objetos cliente e produto no meu *form* onde encontra-se a lista, mas o erro persiste, já tentei inicializar ambos os objetos pelo construtor da classe `Comanda` também, mas nada feito.

Segue o código do form completo:

```
public partial class frmMenu : Form
{
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    Produto produto = new Produto();

    public frmMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAddProduto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        List<Comanda> cmd = new List<Comanda>(); //lista que armazena meus valores de comanda

        cmd.Add(new Comanda
        {
            idComanda = Convert.ToInt32(txtIdComanda.Text), 
            nMesa = Convert.ToInt16(txtMesa.Text),
            produto.nomeProduto = cbxProduto.Text,
            produto.valorUnitario = Convert.ToDouble(txtValorProduto.Text),
        }) ; 

        dgvComanda.DataSource = cmd;
    }


    private void btnLimparComanda_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
    }
}
```

Por que do erro CS0747?

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 1):

Você teria que fazer algo assim:

```
if (!int.TryParse(txtIdComanda.Text out var id) {
    //faz alguma coisa para indicar que deu erro e não permite continuar
}
if (!short.TryParse(txtMesa.Text out var mesa) {
    //faz alguma coisa para indicar que deu erro e não permite continuar
}
if (!decimal.TryParse(txtValorProduto.Text out var valor) {
    //faz alguma coisa para indicar que deu erro e não permite continuar
}
cmd.Add(new Comanda {
    idComanda = id), 
    nMesa = mesa,
    produto = new Produto() {
        nomeProduto = cbxProduto.Text,
        valorUnitario = valor
    }
});
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/InnerInitialization.cs).

Estou criando um objeto do tipo `Produto` e aí sim inicializando seus membros, não pode fazer isso sem criar o objeto. Esse objeto é colocado no campo `produto`.

Aproveitei para corrigir alguns erros do código como não testar se a conversão deu certo antes de dar prosseguimento à execução e usar o [tipo correto para valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101) (claro que precisa mudar na classe também). Não corrigi diversos outros erros nas classes, como por exemplo permitir criar um objeto livremente sem critério algum ou ter *getter*/*setter* para tudo mesmo onde não há necessidade. Algumas coisas não posso falar sem saber de mais detalhes. E não considerei erro, mas o [padrão de nomenclatura não é o usado em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101).

Veja mais em [Qual a principal diferença entre int.Parse() e Convert.ToInt32()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101) e [Diferenças entre Parse vs TryParse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Comment: Muito obrigado, você me deu um norte, quanto aos outros erros ainda vou trabalhar, em níveis de acesso e tratamento de erros, está tudo muito cru ainda. Mas eu tentei instanciar o segundo objeto "Produto" dentro do método Add e ele insiste no erro.

Comment: Eu esqueci de uma parte ali. Mas vou te dar ouro conselho. Tente fazer coisas mais simples, você está com dificuldade de sintaxe básica e fazendo coisas complexas, conforme domina o mais simples aí parte para o mais complexo, quando aprende cheio de lacunas não consegue programar que não é só copiar e decorar coisas, precisa entender tudo o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Agradeço o conselho Maniero.

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu o problema pode aceitar a resposta marcando o verdinho ali do lado esquerdo logo abaixo dos votos que você ainda não pode dar. Pode ver mais no [tour] como funciona.