# O que significam os termos tipos Genéricos, Não Genéricos, Cast, Boxing e Unboxing?

Tags: c#

Alguém pode explicar estes termos tão comumente vistos em C#?

Comment: Relacionada (quase duplicada): [Quais as diferenças entre Tipos Genéricos em C# e em Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10032/18246)

Comment: Duplicada: [O que é programação genérica?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/18246)

Comment: Duplicada: [Qual a diferença entre um cast explícito e o operador as?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47935/18246)

Comment: Duplicada: [Qual a diferença entre usar (int)variavel ou Convert.ToInt32(variavel)?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90928/18246)

Comment: Relacionada: [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/18246)

Comment: Relacionada (quase duplicada): 
[Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/18246)