# Por que acessores tipados executam o processo com maior velocidade?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, ado.net

Eu estava lendo um artigo de [como melhorar o desempenho de um data reader utilizando *ADO.NET*](http://www.macoratti.net/12/11/ado_mdes.htm) e nesse artigo ele cita o uso dos *Typed Accessors* para realizar esta função, pelo que eu entendi ele tem a mesma função do `Convert`, porém acaba fazendo o processo com mais velocidade, segue um exemplo usando o `Convert`:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
          EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["EmployeeID"]);
          LastName = Convert.ToString(dr["LastName"]);
          FirstName = Convert.ToString(dr["FirstName"]);
          city = Convert.ToString(dr["city"]);   
    }
}
```

Agora com o *Typed Accessor*

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
     while (dr.Read())
     {
          EmployeeID = dr.GetInt32(0);
          LastName = dr.GetString(1);
          FirstName = dr.IsDBNull(2) ? null : dr.GetString(2);
          city = dr.GetString(3);
     }
}
```

Por que com o uso dos acessores tipados o tempo de acesso ao `DataReader` é mais rápido? E o que são de fato os *typed acessors*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ele tem a função oposta do `Convert`. Ele tem a função de te entregar o dado já com o tipo que precisa, assim não precisa de conversão e não precisar fazer isto é mais rápido. Não só isto, até porque em alguns casos nem deve dar mais desempenho porque para entregar o dado no tipo esperado há um tratamento interno que pode ser tão custoso quando a conversão, mas há casos que você evita alocação de memória e dupla conversão, tanto para colocar o dado em um objeto no *heap*, quanto para retirá-lo de lá, e isso tudo custa, gera pressão no *garbage collector*. Quanto menos alocar mais pode ter performance.

De qualquer forma achei o teste um pouco ingênuo. Eu faria um teste muito mais extensivo para ver em quais situações há perda, eu não acho que seja tão linear. Testes de performance não são simples de fazer porque pode ter muita variável que interfere no resultado sem a pessoa se dar conta.

Pra falar a verdade, em C# isso nem deveria acontecer. Essa API é antiga e foi pensada em uma época que o C# não tinha todos recursos necessários para lidar com isso de forma apropriada. Não a toa que um ORM como o Dapper consegue fazer muito mais de forma muito mais robusta com a mesma ou mais performance. No começo o C# abusava do uso de objetos do tipo `object`, que são sempre alocados no *heap* e precisam sempre de um esforço extra para acessá-lo, já que um objeto puro por si só não tem funcionalidade prática para a aplicação. Você tem que convertê-lo para um tipo que tem utilidade, como um inteiro, por exemplo.

Também pesa um pouco o fato do acesso na primeira forma ser por um dicionário e não por uma forma direta na estrutura que veio do banco de dados, isto está demonstrado na página *linkada* na pergunta. Mas pra mim o que mais importa é que essa forma não é robusta, mais que ser mais lenta. Não que a segunda forma seja muito melhor, na verdade ela pode ser pior porque depende um pouco de como o dado foi pedido para o banco de dados e como a estrutura dele está nesse momento, então a posição do campo pode variar e em alguns casos nem dar erro, mas produzir resultados errados.

Eu sou a favor de acesso direto ao banco de dados ou o uso de um Micro ORM como o Dapper. O ADO.NET pode ser usado sem problemas, mas é uma tecnologia mal arquitetada para os padrões atuais, então quando o usa, abre mão de ter o melhor possível.

"Acessores" tipados são métodos de acesso (métodos do tipo *get*) que retornam um objeto já com um tipo específico, ao contrário de retornar um `object` acéfalo que precisa de conversão, portanto o objeto tem tipo (tecnicamente `object` é um tipo, mas não um inútil para quase todos os usos).

Algumas perguntas que ajudarão entender melhor sobre o assunto:

- [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre um cast explícito e o operador as?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47935/101)
- [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101)
- [Boxing está copiando os dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55147/101)
- [Diferença entre object, dynamic e var](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/101)
- [Por que o unboxing só pode ser feito para o tipo que foi realizado o boxing anteriormente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220870/101)
- [Qual diferença entre Boolean e boolean?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160914/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre usar (int)variavel ou Convert.ToInt32(variavel)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90928/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi, olhando melhor só o fato da palavra `Get` já indica que não é uma conversão, não prestei muita atenção. Vou pesquisar melhor sobre Micro ORMs principalmente a respeito do Dapper.