# Converter string para float no C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, terminologia

No que aprendi até agora quando queremos utilizar o comando `Console.Readline()` para ler dados que o usuário digita temos que efetuar uma conversão quando esses dados não forem do tipo *string*, conheço o comando `.Parse()`, porém por habito tenho utilizado o comando `Convert.ToInt16()` por exemplo, porém notei que existe um "Convert"... para quase todos os formatos exceto para o `Float`, eu sei que poderia usar o `Convert.ToDouble`, que serviria da mesma forma, ou ate mesmo o `Float.Parse()`, mas queria saber porque não posso usar o `Convert` para `float`.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 5):

Todos esses estão errados para o propósito descrito. Se é indeterminado se o dado está correto não pode confiar nele, então é normal se ele está errado, inválido, que não pode ser convertido, por isso a única forma correta para realizar esta operação é tentar converter e verificar se a operação deu certo ou não. Embora funcione de outra formas, a mais correta e eficiente é o uso do `TryParse()`. O seu uso já foi respondido em [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). Veja também [porque o uso do `Convert` é inadequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101). Veja também sobre o [uso de *cast*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90928/101).

Isto vale para qualquer tipo de conversão, não apenas para *float*. Se você tem um texto e não é garantido do que está escrito ali precisa fazer o processo de *parsing* para entender o que tem no texto, validar e aí fazer a conversão. O `Parse()` pode ser usado quando você tem certeza que o dado é válido e certamente será convertido corretamente, o que não é o caso em entrada de dados pelo console.

O tipo `float` tem seu [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.tryparse?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), use-o e nem precisa se preocupar com isso.

Também não existe um `Convert.ToInt()` porque o tipo do *framework* não chama `int` (existe um `Convert.ToInt32()` que é o nome que o .NET usa), assim como o `float` para C# é o mesmo que o `Single` para o .NET. O .NET precisa trabalhar com o nome universal do tipo, então existe um [`Convert.ToSingle()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tosingle?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). O nome `float` é só um [alias que o C# usa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3711/101), não o nome oficial do tipo que pode ser usado para outras linguagens.

Mas toda vez que encontrar uma *string* o ideal não é converter e sim *parsear*. Mesmo que você tenha uma situação que garanta que o dado é um número válido de tipo flutuante o mais correto é o uso do `float.Parse()`. Um caso que poderia ser útil usar o `Convert.ToSingle()` é se o valor pode ser nulo, mas esse padrão deveria ser evitado, pelo menos deveria verificar antes. Se a linguagem fosse criada hoje este método nem existiria.

Mas tem diversas outras perguntas mostrando o uso correto (isto é uma das coisas mais mal-usadas pelos programadores).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

O Float é chamado de [`Single`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/single-data-type) no .NET Framework. Utilize a classe `System.Single` para realizar conversões `float`.

```
float numero = global::System.Single.Parse("2.5");
```

O C# utiliza o padrão das linguagens C e herdou o nome `float`. `float` é um número flutuante de **uma única** precisão, já `double`, é um número flutuante de **dupla** precisão.

Comment: De fato existe um Convert.ToSingle que funcionou com o float, muito obrigado, era mais uma questão conceitual, queria entender como funcionava.