# Como arredondar um numero decimal para outro decimal mais próximo?

Tags: c#, funções, decimal, arredondamento

Então gente estou tendo muita dificuldade em criar uma calculadora de desconto. Por exemplo:
quero que um numero `x =  2,27` vire 2,3
e `x = 2,24` fique 2,2.

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Também pode ser útil: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21941/101

Comment: Uma forma simples é você cria uma variável do tipo `decimal` para receber esse valores e ao apresenta-los você usa a função `ToString()`, fica algo mais ou menos assim: declaração da variável `decimal numero = 0;` atribuição do valor para ela `numero = 1.33M;` obtendo o valor arredondado: `MessageBox.Show(numero.ToString("N1")); //Resultado: 1,3`, outro exemplo: `numero = 1.35M;` resultado: `MessageBox.Show(numero.ToString("N1")); //Resultado: 1,4`