# Como arredondar número?

Tags: php

Estou precisando utilizar a seguinte lógica para arredondar:

Números entre x.1 e x.9 serão arredondados para x.5, ou seja, ficaria assim utilizando exemplos:

```
1.0 = 1;
1.2 = 1.5;
1.9 = 1.5;
```

Alguma ideia sobre como fazer isso? Tentei encontrar uma função pronta do próprio PHP mas não encontrei.

Comment: PHP tem funções semelhantes, [round](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.round.php), [ceil](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ceil.php) e [floor](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floor.php).Já o que você quer, você teria que adaptar. Na própria página do [round](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.round.php#114573) tem um exemplo do que você quer, talvez te ajude.

Comment: Veja como eu dei uma solução em C#: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21941/101

Answer (score 1):

### Pode usar a função [`fmod()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fmod.php)

```
function arred ($n) {
    $r = fmod($n, 1.0);
    if ($r != 0) {
        return $n - $r + 0.5;
    } else {
        return $n;
    }
}
```

Script com testes: http://codepad.org/slXVpUti.

Answer (score 0):

Pode simplesmente verificar se o valor inteiro é igual, isso é:

```
$inteiro = intval($numero);

if(($numero - $inteiro) !== 0e0){
      // Então adicionar $inteiro + 0.5
}
```

Poderia fazer algo como por exemplo:

```
function arredondar(float $numero) : string {

        $inteiro = intval($numero); 
        $adicionar = '0';

        if(($numero - $inteiro) !== 0e0){
            $adicionar = '0.5' * ($numero > 0 ?: -1);
        }

        return bcadd($inteiro, $adicionar, 1);
}
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/998964a2ae57ad9baa1ed309ec0c55415cabbb7a)

Acho que não há muito o que explicar. Se o resultado de `$numero - $inteiro` for diferente de `0` ele vai acrescentar `0.5` (ou `-0.5` se o número for negativo).

Uma outra opção, mais fácil seria somente concatenar o `.5` ao número inteiro se ele cair na condição, isso iria remover a necessidade de qualquer soma.

```
function arredondar(float $numero) : float {

        $inteiro = intval($numero); 

        if(($numero - $inteiro) !== 0e0){
            $inteiro .= '.5';
        }

        return $inteiro;
}
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b36aea8dfbd991592830bb82d062baf7d830563f)

---

Se quiser arrendondar normalmente utilize `round()`.