# Arredondar decimais com PHP

Tags: php, matemática, arredondamento

Preciso arredondar números decimais para baixo, **exceto** quando a casa decimal for 5, por exemplo 1.2 quero arredondar para 1 e quando o número for 1.5 quero permanecer o valor. Eu conheço apenas 3 funções do **PHP** para arredondar: *floor, ceil* e *round* mas nenhum trabalha dessa forma. A função *floor* arredonda para baixo mas ele arredonda 1.5 para 1. Outro detalhe estou trabalhando apenas com 1 casa decimal.
Tentei criar uma função para fazer esse tratamento mas infelizmente não consegui.

```
// Utilizando as funções nativas do PHP.

echo round( 1.2 ); // 1
echo round( 1.5 ); // 2
echo round( 1.6 ); // 2

echo ceil( 1.2 ); // 2
echo ceil( 1.5 ); // 2
echo ceil( 1.6 ); // 2

echo floor( 1.2 ); // 1
echo floor( 1.5 ); // 1
echo floor( 1.6 ); // 1

// A forma que eu preciso
1.2 => 1
1.5 => 1.5
1.6 => 1.5
```

Comment: 5 ou superior, voce deseja manter?

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada nessa resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/6619392/6691854 e fazer uma function, verificando o decimal.

Comment: Essa é quase igual em C#: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21941/101

Comment: @JulioHenrique97 Se a casa decimal for menor que 5, quero arredondar para menos, se for igual a 5 quero manter e se for acima de 5 quero arredondar para baixo, ficando assim: 1.2 => 1, 1.5 => 1.5, 1.6 => 1.5